# Запись списка в txt файл в питоне

Tags: python

Собственно как записать результат работы функции в txt файл?

```
f = open( '***.txt', 'w' )
f.write( '??????' )
f.close()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:

```
f.write("\n".join(list).join("\n"));
```

---

```
for item in list:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

---

```
import pickle
# Хороший вариант для не-string списков, т.к мы зайдействуем сериализацию
# с помощью pickle. Можно сериализовать в json или, например, xml.
pickle.dump(list, f)
```

---

**P.S** Первый вариант хорош тем, что все действия выполняются в 1 строчку, но плох в плане того, что строчка конструируется **целиком,** и только лишь потом выполняется запись.

Answer (score 8):

Чтобы записать в файл текстовое представление элементов списка через пробел в Питоне 3:

```
with open("файл.txt", "w") as file:
    print(*список, file=file)
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Если хочется каждый элемент на своей строчке напечатать:

```
print(*список, file=file, sep="\n")
```

Можно руками отформатировать (тот же результат):

```
print("\n".join(map(str, список)), file=file)
```

Или напечатать по одному элементу за раз (тот же результат):

```
for item in список:
    print(item, file=file)
```

Чтобы сохранить в JSON формате:

```
import json 

with open("список.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(список, file)
```

Чтобы сохранить как csv:

```
import csv 

with open("список.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerow(список)
```

Код продолжает работать даже если элементы содержат запятые, кавычки, новые строки внутри.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    txt_file.write(text)
```

text - результат выполнения функции