# Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в параметрах функций?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру, что делает `*` (астериск) в следующем коде:

```
print(*min(p for p in counter.items() if p[1] == max_count))

print(*team, *coef)

seasons = [datetime(*args) for args in [
    (Y, 1, 1), # winter
    (Y, 3, 1), # spring
    (Y, 6, 1), # summer
    (Y, 9, 1), # autumn
    (Y, 12, 1) # winter
]]

def lcm(*args):
    """Least common multiple."""
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a * b // gcd(a, b), args)

async def watchdog(loop, last_activity_time, timeout, func, *args):
    "Run *func(*args)* if more than *timeout* seconds since *last_activity_time*."
    while (loop.time() - last_activity_time()) < timeout:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return func(*args)
```

и что делают две `**` звёздочки:

```
'{a:.{n}f}'.format(**vars())

class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [What does `**` (double star) and `*` (star) do for parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Звёздочка в Питоне помимо [умножения `x*y` (`help('*')`) и возведения
в степень `x**y`
(`help('**')`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-14)<sup>†</sup>
используется, чтобы обозначить **ноль или более** чего-либо.

К примеру в описании параметров функции:

```
def f(*args):
    print(args)
```

[`*` означает, что функция принимает ноль или более аргументов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-22),
которые доступны внутри функции в виде кортежа `args`:

```
>>> f(1,'a')
(1, 'a')
```

Для именованных параметров используются [две
звёздочки](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-39):

```
def g(a, b, *args, name='default', **kwargs):
    print(a, b, args, name, kwargs)
```

здесь `g()` принимает два обязательных аргумента и произвольное (ноль или более) количество
других аргументов:

```
>>> g(1, b=2, c=3)
1 2 () default {'c': 3}
```

`kwargs`—это словарь дополнительных аргументов, переданных по имени (`c` в данном случае). А
`args` это пустой кортеж `()`, так как дополнительных позиционных
аргументов не было передано.

После `*` все параметры обязаны передаваться по имени,
[пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584614/23044):

```
def min_item(items, *, key=lambda x: x):
    ...
```

При вызове, если задан, `key` обязан быть указан по имени:
`min([1,2,-3], key=abs)`.

Принятие произвольного количества аргументов может быть полезно при
создании функций-обёрток:

```
def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
    flush = kwargs.pop('flush', True) # flush unless overriden
    print(*args, flush=flush, **kwargs)
```

[При множественном наследовании
`**kwargs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591493/23044) помогает
реализовать требование совместимости параметров для методов базовых классов, так как `kwargs` позволяет передать произвольные именованные аргументы.

Видно, что звёздочку можно использовать и [при вызове
функции](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-38):

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
s = "abc"
print(*L, *s) # iterable unpacking: print(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c')
# -> 1 2 3 a b c
```

произвольные коллекции (iterable в общем случае) `L`, `s` распаковываются и каждый их элемент передаётся в виде отдельного агрумента в вызываемую функцию (`print()`).

Можно использовать и при явном присваивании:

```
>>> first, *middle, last = L
>>> first, middle, last
(1, [2], 3)
```

в этом случае первый и последний аргументы из списка `L` распаковываются в явно
приведённые имена (`first`, `last`), а остаток ноль или более
элементов в виде списка помещаются в `middle`.

Звёздочку можно использовать и при задании списков, кортежей, наборов и
словарей в исходном коде, используя соответствующий синтаксис ([tuple,
list, set](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-78), and [dictionary
displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-14)):

```
>>> *range(4), 4
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> [*range(4), 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> {*range(4), 4}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> {'x': 1, **{'y': 2}} # dictionary unpacking inside dictionary display
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

Тонкий момент: запятая в Питоне создаёт кортеж—скобки нужны только для
пустого кортежа `()`. Поэтому первая строчка равнозначна: `(*range(4), 4)`.

Так же как и при вызове функций, звёздочка распаковывает коллекцию здесь и действует как будто каждый элемент был передан отдельно в соответствующие конструкторы.

Таким образом можно [сложить два
словаря](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044) или произвольные отображения ([Mapping](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)):

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> b = {'a': 3, 'c': 0}
>>> {**a, **b}
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 0}
>>> {**b, **a}
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
```

При наличии дублирующих ключей, более поздние значения побеждают, [как обычно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34539772/4279): `{'a': 1, 'a': 3} == {'a': 3}`.

Знание, что делает звёздочка полезно, чтобы объяснить как [`zip(*matrix)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279) транспонирует квадратную матрицу или как обойти итератор по ровно `n` элементов за раз: [`zip(*[iterator]*n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/4279).

Помимо указанных значений, звёздочка может присутствовать в имени
файла для создания шаблона (wildcard), [к
примеру](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

print(*Path().glob('*.py'))
print(*Path().glob('**/*.py'))
```

Первый `print()` печатает через пробел все (ноль или более) имена файлов в текущей директории с расширением `.py`. Подобный (`*.py`) синтаксис популярен, так как он используется в командной строке (shell).
Второй `print()` с двумя звёздочками (`'**/*.py'`) выводит имена Питон-файлов во всем дереве директорий (включая вложенные директории).

[В регулярных
выражениях](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)
`*` означает повторение ноль или более раз:

```
import re

if re.fullmatch(r'x*', text):
    print('текст пустой или содержит только `x`')
```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> умножение натуральных чисел `n*m` можно рассматривать как повторение сложения (ноль или более) раз. Аналогично, возведение в степень `n**m` можно рассматривать как повторение умножения:</sup>

```
 2  * 3 ==  2 + 2 + 2
 2 ** 3 ==  2 * 2 * 2
[2] * 3 == [2,  2,  2]
```

Comment: `{**a, **b}` не работает в питоне 3.4. Укажите что с какой версии работает.

Comment: @SmitJohnth можно, но и так много информации в ответе. Текущая версия Python уже 3.6 Кого интересуют подробности, могут на ссылку нажать — там версия приведена (я для того ссылки и привожу, чтобы у кого желание есть, могли больше деталей получить).

Comment: Что, 2.7 уже закопали?

Comment: @SmitJohnth у вопроса есть метка python-3.x и нет метки python-2.7 Если есть желание, вы можете аналогичный вопрос для Питона 2 спросить (отличий много, ответ и так много материала по самым верхам покрывает).

Comment: У вопроса метка 3.х потому что автора вопроса интересовал 3.х. Если уж решили сделать мегаответ - логично было бы указывать версии питона с которых это работает хотя бы если фичи не работают в 2.7.

Comment: @SmitJohnth посмотрите на автора вопроса. Ещё раз, если вас что-то другое интересует, то задайте свой вопрос (я уверен, что мне известны намерения автора текущего вопроса).

Comment: Вообще благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Звездочка `(*)` в Питоне используется для разбора аргументов. Она указывает, что передаваемый объект должен быть разобран (распакован) в отдельные аргументы.

В первом примере кода `*min(p for p in counter.items() if p[1] == max_count)` разбирается в аргументы и передается в функцию print.

Во втором примере переменные `team` и `coef` разбираются в отдельные аргументы и передаются в функцию `print`.

В третьем примере `*args` разбирается в отдельные аргументы и передается в функцию `datetime`.

В четвертом примере `*args` разбирается в отдельные аргументы и передается в функцию reduce.

В пятом примере `*args` разбирается в отдельные аргументы и передается в функцию watchdog.

Две звездочки (**) также используются для разбора аргументов, но в этом случае объект разбирается в словарь из именованных аргументов.

В первом примере `'{a:.{n}f}'.format(**vars())` звездочки указывают, что `vars()` должен быть разобран в словарь из именованных аргументов, которые затем используются в функции `format`.

Во втором примере в классе `A` в методе `init **kwargs` разбирается в словарь из именованных аргументов, которые затем передаются в вызов функции `super().init`.

Оба эти примера используют разбор аргументов для упрощения кода и улучшения его читаемости.

---

Еще один пример использования разбора аргументов с двумя звездочками:

```
def some_function(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

some_function(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
```

В этом примере функция `some_function` ожидает передачу именованных аргументов. Когда мы вызываем функцию some_function с аргументами `arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3`, они разбираются в словарь из именованных аргументов `{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3}` и передаются в функцию `some_function`. В результате вызова функции будет выведено `{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3}`.

Разбор аргументов с использованием звездочек может быть особенно полезен в случаях, когда нужно передать большое количество аргументов в функцию или когда нужно передать список или словарь в качестве аргумента. Разбор аргументов позволяет упростить эти операции, делая код более читаемым.

---

Давайте рассмотрим еще несколько примеров использования разбора аргументов:

```
def some_function(arg1, arg2, *args):
   print(arg1, arg2, args)

some_function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

В этом примере функция `some_function` ожидает передачу двух обязательных аргументов `arg1` и `arg2`, а также любого количества дополнительных аргументов. Когда мы вызываем функцию `some_function` с аргументами `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, то первые два аргумента присваиваются `arg1` и arg2 соответственно, а остальные три аргумента разбираются в кортеж args. В результате вызова функции будет выведено `1, 2, (3, 4, 5)`.

---

Еще один пример:

```
def some_function(arg1, **kwargs):
print(arg1, kwargs)

some_function(1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
```

В этом примере функция `some_function` ожидает передачу одного обязательного аргумента `arg1` и любого количества дополнительных именованных аргументов. Когда мы вызываем функцию `some_function` с аргуменентами `1, arg2=2, arg3=3`, то первый аргумент присваивается arg1, а остальные аргументы разбираются в словарь `kwargs`. В результате вызова функции будет выведено `1, {'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3}`.

---

Еще один пример:

```
def some_function(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
print(arg1, args, kwargs)

some_function(1, 2, 3, arg4=4, arg5=5)
```

В этом примере функция `some_function` ожидает передачу одного обязательного аргумента `arg1`, любого количества дополнительных аргументов и любого количества дополнительных именованных аргументов. Когда мы вызываем функцию `some_function` с аргументами `1, 2, 3, arg4=4, arg5=5`, то первый аргумент присваивается `arg1`, второй и третий аргументы разбираются в кортеж `args`, а остальные аргументы разбираются в словарь `kwargs`. В результате вызова функции будет выведено `1, (2, 3), {'arg4': 4, 'arg5': 5}`.

---

Одним из примеров использования разбора аргументов с звездочками может быть реализация функции, которая принимает на вход список чисел и возвращает список элементов, которые больше среднего значения списка.

```
def average_filter(numbers):
    avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    return [x for x in numbers if x > avg]

print(average_filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

В этом примере функция `average_filter` принимает на вход список чисел и вычисляет среднее значение списка. Затем функция использует генератор списка, чтобы создать список элементов, которые больше среднего значения. В результате вызова функции со списком `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` будет возвращен список `[4, 5]`.

---

Один из примеров использования разбора аргументов с звездочками в сочетании с генераторами списков может быть реализация функции, которая принимает на вход список строк и возвращает список строк, отсортированный в порядке убывания длины строк.

```
def sort_by_length(strings):
return sorted(strings, key=lambda s: len(s), reverse=True)

print(sort_by_length(['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'ijkl']))
```

В этом примере функция sort_by_length использует генератор списка `sorted` и лямбда-функцию, чтобы отсортировать список строк в порядке убывания длины. В результате вызова функции со списком `['abc', 'def', 'gh', 'ijkl']` будет возвращен список `['ijkl', 'abc', 'def', 'gh']`.

---

Один из примеров использования разбора аргументов с звездочками в сочетании с лямбда-функциями может быть реализация функции, которая принимает на вход список чисел и возвращает список элементов, которые делятся на `3` без остатка.

```
def multiple_of_3(numbers):
return list(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, numbers))

print(multiple_of_3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

В этом примере функция `multiple_of_3` использует функцию `filter` и лямбда-функцию, чтобы отфильтровать список чисел и вернуть список элементов, которые делятся на `3` без остатка