# Как вытащить имя массива JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Получаю такой фрагмент массива JSON, вопрос в том, как можно вытащить имя(?) массива через Python
Тоесть, число которое будет стоять на месте 1477770720169

```
{
  '1477770720169': {
    'rights': {
      '1477770395835': {
        'ua_company_name': '',
        'eng_fullname': '',
        'ukr_company_name': '',
        'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
        'citizen': '',
        'ukr_firstname': '',
        'ua_lastname': '',
        'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '',
        'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '',
        'ua_firstname': '',
        'eng_lastname': '',
        'eng_firstname': '',
        'percent-ownership': '',
        'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '',
        'otherOwnership': '',
        'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
        'ua_streetType': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
        'rights_cityPath': '',
        'eng_company_name': '',
        'ua_middlename': '',
        'postCode': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
        'ukr_fullname': '',
        'ua_city': '',
        'eng_postCode': '',
        'ua_street': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
        'ua_postCode': '',
        'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
        'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
        'eng_middlename': '',
        'rightBelongs': '1477770395835',
        'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
        'ukr_middlename': '',
        'percent-ownership_extendedstatus': '1',
        'ua_street_extendedstatus': '',
        'ownershipType': 'Спільна власність',
        'ukr_lastname': ''
      }
    },
    'costAssessment_extendedstatus': '1',
    'ua_postCode': '27403',
    'totalArea': '48',
    'otherObjectType': '',
    'iteration': '1477770720169',
    'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '1',
    'city': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'costAssessment': '',
    'ua_streetType': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'ua_cityType': "Знам'янка / Кіровоградська область / Україна",
    'owningDate': '14.10.2004',
    'postCode': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'costDate': '9265',
    'cityPath': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'person': '1477770395835',
    'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '1',
    'country': '1',
    'district': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'region': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'ua_street': '[Конфіденційна інформація]',
    'objectType': 'Житловий будинок'
  }
}
```

Comment: print(''.join(x for x in s.keys())), где s - это словарь. Можете предварительно присвоить значение и проверить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе у вас не JSON (json  не использует одинарные кавычки для строк). У вас показано текстовое представление словаря (ассоциативные массивы принято называть "словарь" в Питоне), то как он в исходном коде задаётся в Питоне.

Чтобы напечатать все ключи в заданном словаре `d`, достаточно его обойти:

```
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

Или через пробел: [`print(*d)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044).

Словари в Питоне это *неупорядоченная* коллекция пар ключ/значение. Если вы хотите первый попавшийся ключ (всё равно какой) из словаря вытащить:

```
>>> next(iter(d))
'1477770720169'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {'1477770720169': {'rights': {'1477770395835': {'ua_company_name': '', 'eng_fullname': '', 'ukr_company_name': '', 'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': '', 'citizen': '', 'ukr_firstname': '', 'ua_lastname': '', 'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '', 'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '', 'ua_firstname': '', 'eng_lastname': '', 'eng_firstname': '', 'percent-ownership': '', 'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '', 'otherOwnership': '', 'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '', 'ua_streetType': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'rights_cityPath': '', 'eng_company_name': '', 'ua_middlename': '', 'postCode': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'ukr_fullname': '', 'ua_city': '', 'eng_postCode': '', 'ua_street': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'ua_postCode': '', 'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '', 'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '', 'eng_middlename': '', 'rightBelongs': '1477770395835', 'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '', 'ukr_middlename': '', 'percent-ownership_extendedstatus': '1', 'ua_street_extendedstatus': '', 'ownershipType': 'Спільна власність', 'ukr_lastname': ''}}, 'costAssessment_extendedstatus': '1', 'ua_postCode': '27403', 'totalArea': '48', 'otherObjectType': '', 'iteration': '1477770720169', 'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '1', 'city': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'costAssessment': '', 'ua_streetType': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'ua_cityType': "Знам'янка / Кіровоградська область / Україна", 'owningDate': '14.10.2004', 'postCode': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'costDate': '9265', 'cityPath': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'person': '1477770395835', 'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '1', 'country': '1', 'district': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'region': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'ua_street': '[Конфіденційна інформація]', 'objectType': 'Житловий будинок'}}
>>> a.keys()
['1477770720169']
>>> a.keys()[0]
'1477770720169'
```

Так?

Comment: В Python 3 не сработает

Comment: >>> a.keys()
dict_keys(['1477770720169'])
>>> a.keys()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing