# как избежать погрешности c типом float в задаче по Python?

Tags: python, float

Условие:
Пирожок в столовой стоит a рублей и b копеек. Определите, сколько рублей и копеек нужно заплатить за n пирожков. Программа получает на вход три числа: a, b, n, и должна вывести два числа: стоимость покупки в рублях и копейках.
Во время проверки ответ неправильный из-за погрешности типа float

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
n = int(input())
a*=n
b*=n
if b >= 100 :
 abc= b / 100
else : 
 abc = 0
print (a+int(abc), (abc-int(abc)))
```

[image: Во время проверки ответ неправильные из-за погрешности типа float]

Comment: а зачем так сложно? посчитайте все в копейках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как верно заметил @SergeyPanasenko, можно считать в копейках. Это не только позволит избежать погрешности, но и сделает код более простым и понятным.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
n = int(input())

a *= n
b *= n
a += b // 100  # Целочисленное деление.
b %= 100       # Остаток от деления.

print(a, "руб.", b, "коп.")
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас просто код неверен. `0.32…` это неправильное количество копеек—погрешность, связанная с float вычислениями тут ни при чём. Указанный тест, который ломается на вашем коде, работает даже с float :

```
#XXX НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТОТ КОД (ПРИВЕДЁН ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ИЛЛЮСТРАЦИИ)
>>> a, b, n = 2029, 34, 1848
>>> f = (a + b/100)
>>> f
2029.34
>>> f *= n
>>> f
3750220.32
>>> print(int(f), round((f - int(f)) * 100))
3750220 32
```

Хотя в общем случае почти все действительные числа не могут быть представлены точно используя [`float` (запись в научной нотации (аналог 1,02×10<sup>3</sup>), используя конечное число двоичных цифр)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9). И в данном случае легко использовать целочисленные вычисления, используя только умножение и сложение, чтобы всегда точный ответ в копейках получить:

```
>>> a, b, n = 2029, 34, 1848
>>> print(*divmod((a * 100 + b) * n, 100))
3750220 32
```

[`divmod(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod) возвращает `(x // y, x % y)` для целых и используется здесь, чтобы разбить итоговую сумму в копейках на рубли и копейки:

```
>>> divmod(123, 100) # 123 копейки, 100 копеек в рубле
(1, 23) # рубль и 23 копейки
```

[`print(*t)` здесь описан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044).