# Синхронная сортировка списков Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть два <strike>стула</strike> списка **a** и **b**

Надо синхронно отсортировать их по списку **a**, т.е.
первому элементу списка **a** соответствует первый элемент списка **b** и т.д.

```
a = [3, 1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
...
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
b1 = ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

сделаем это последовательно

```
a = [3, 1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

#соединим два списка специальной функцией zip
x = zip(a,b)

#x теперь [(3, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]

#отсортируем, взяв первый элемент каждого списка как ключ
xs = sorted(x, key=lambda tup: tup[0])

#xs = [(1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a')]

#и последний шаг - извлечем
a1 = [x[0] for x in xs]
b1 = [x[1] for x in xs]
```

Comment: Если есть желание zip использовать, можно упростить: `a1, b1 = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))`

Answer (score 2):

Можно индексы отсортировать, используя значения из `a` списка:

```
indices = sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i])
```

После этого легко получить "синхронно" отсортированные a,b списки:

```
>>> [a[i] for i in indices]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [b[i] for i in indices]
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Это достаточно распространённый случай, к примеру существует [`numpy.argsort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 1, 2])
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
indices = a.argsort()
print(a[indices])  # -> [1 2 3]
print(b[indices])  # -> ['b' 'c' 'a']
```

Для полноты, вот менее читаемый для новичков код в более [functional programming](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) стиле:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

a = [3, 1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
indices = sorted(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)
print(*map(a.__getitem__, indices))  # -> 1 2 3
print(*map(b.__getitem__, indices))  # -> b c a
```

[`print(*...)` здесь объяснено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044).

Иногда [`operator.itemgetter` может пригодиться](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_by_a = itemgetter(*indices)
print(sorted_by_a(a))  # -> (1, 2, 3)
print(sorted_by_a(b))  # -> ('b', 'c', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, 1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b1 = [y for x,y in sorted(zip(a,b))] # отсортировали пары a/b и забрали только буквы
a1 = sorted(a)
print a1
print b1
```