# Можно ли как-то создать список всех ключей словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, у меня есть:

```
dict_1 ={'1' : ['1', '1', '2'], '2':['1','2','3']}
```

Результат:

```
['1','2']
```

Comment: @jfs Ваша правда. Удалил коммент

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Чтобы получить список ключей словаря:

```
>>> list(dict_1)
['1', '2']
```

Просто обход словаря в Питоне возвращает ключи, поэтому к примеру, чтобы напечатать все ключи:

```
print(*dict_1)
```

Вот [описание, что звёздочка `*` делает в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044).

То есть совсем не обязательно список создавать, чтобы посмотреть на ключи словаря.

[`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) возвращает *вид* (view) словаря в Питоне 3, который поддерживает операции над множеством ключей (set):

```
>>> dict_1.keys() & {'1', '2', '3'}
{'2', '1'}
```

В Питоне 2, `dict.keys()` метод возвращал список ключей. Можно использовать [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) на Питоне 2, чтобы получить Питон 3 set-like поведение.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = []
for key in sorted(dict_1.keys()):
... L.append(key)
L
['1', '2']
```

так вроде не очень сложно... sorted() нужна (или нет...), так как пары ключ-значение не упорядочены в словарях.

Comment: Сложнее чем соседний ответ)

Comment: скорее длиннее, я бы сказал, зато интуитивно понятнее, на мой взгляд.  & {'1', '2', '3'} вот это еще надо как-то объяснить челу, кот. не знает словари. Верно же...а первый пример немного не ясен - те почему list() обходит только ключи...ну не интуитивно понятно...