# Обработка данных при вводе(python)

Tags: python

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int ci;
        scanf("%d", &ci);
        int mn = INF, mx = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < ci; ++j) {
            int x;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            mx = max(mx, x);
            mn = min(mn, x);
        }
        a[i] = make_pair(mn, mx);
    }
```

Требуется реализовать похожий код на питоне. Т.е. необходим только максимальный и минимальный элемент в строке. Но при этом время выполнения программы не позволяет записать все в список и уже в нем найти минимум и максимум. 
Пример строка 1 2 3 4 на вводе и необходимо найти 1 и 4. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
digits = [0,0]
input_digits = input('Enter digits with comma (,) separator :').split(',')

for digit in input_digits:
  if int(digits[0]) > int(digit):
      digits[0] = digit

  if int(digits[1]) < int(digit):
      digits[1] = digit


print(digits);
```

[image: Sandbox result]
[Песочница](https://repl.it/Ewi0/0)

Comment: Конечно, можно было бы сделать со словарями - но заморачиваться не стал. Этот ответ рабочий. Протестировать можете с песочки.

Comment: будет ли этот код работать быстрее, чем например: a = list(map(int, input().split())) max(a)

Comment: @Denzila, Распределение памяти совершенно другое. Не могу точно сказать на сколько быстрее/медленнее оно будет работать.

Comment: в приведенном вами примере строка читается посимвольно или целиком?

Comment: можно ли в питоне, каким-то образом читать строку, разделенную пробелами, посимвольно?

Comment: @Denzila, естественно целиком. После - разделет по сепаратору.

Comment: @Denzila, можно читать посимвольно - но будет долго и расход памяти увеличится.

Comment: а можете привести пример, если нетрудно?

Comment: @Denzila, думаю не стоит делать в данном случае считівание посимвольно :) Будет бесполезно.

Comment: @Denzila если все числа будут отрицательными, max останется нулем

Answer (score 0):

```
st = '2 1 3 41 7 5 6'
gs = map(int, st.split())  # generator
mn = mx = next(gs)  # min=max=первый_элемент(int)
for s in gs:
    if mn > s: mn = s
    if mx < s: mx = s
print(mn, mx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти минимум и максимум обойдя произвольно большую (но конечную) коллекцию чисел только единожды (single-pass algorithm):

```
def minmax(iterable, *, default=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    min_ = max_ = next(it, default)
    for item in it:
        if min_ > item:
            min_ = item
        if max_ < item:
            max_ = item
    return min_, max_
```

Чтобы читать числа, разделённые пробелом из стандартного ввода или файлов, заданных с командной строки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Usage: minmax [<file>...]"""
import fileinput

print(*minmax(n for line in fileinput.input()
              for n in map(int, line.split())))
```

[Что * означает, см. здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044).