# Из txt файла в dict на Python

Tags: python, словари

Есть txt файл

```
smt1 a b c d
smt2 e f g
smt3 h i j k l
```

Как открыть его подобным образом в Python?

```
dct = {
        'smt1': {'a', 'b', 'c','d'},
        'smt2': {'e', 'f', 'g'},
        'smt3': {'h', 'i', 'j','k','l'}
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы значения были типа set? (как в примере в вопросе показано) Или обычных списков (list) достаточно?

Comment: @jfs судя по всему автору уже и не нужно. наверняка, ему необходимы повторяющиеся списки

Answer (score 9):

Файл—это итератор над строками в Питоне, поэтому его можно передать в цикл напрямую:

```
d = {}
with open("файл.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, *value = line.split()
        d[key] = value
```

`with`-конструкция закрывает файл, при выходе из блока, чтобы избежать утечки ресурсов даже если произойдёт ошибка.

`.split()` разбивает строку по произвольному пробелу, позволяя использовать к примеру табы (`'\t'`) или несколько пробелов подряд для разделения полей в строке.

`*value`—это Питон 3 синтаксис. См.  [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Как понимаю, вам нужно получить данные из текстового файла в виде словаря. Навряд ли вам нужно set-множество, и вам нужен следующий результат:

```
dict = {
   'smt1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
   'smt2': ['e', 'f', 'g'], 
   'smt3': ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
}
```

Открываем файл на чтение и разбиваем построчно.

```
file = open("text")
onstring = file.read().split("\n")[:-1]
```

В результате получаем список следущего вида

```
['smt1 a b c d', 'smt2 e f g', 'smt3 h i j k l']
```

Полученный список перебираем, каждый элемент разбиваем по разделителю - `" "`. Первый элемент разбиения будет ключем нашего словаря, список из остальных  - значением.

```
dict = dict()

for item in onstring:
    key = item.split(" ")[0]
    value = item.split(" ")[1:]
    dict[key] = value

file.close()
```

Получаем требуемый результат

```
{'smt1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'smt2': ['e', 'f', 'g'], 'smt3': ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']}
```

Только учтите, что если ключ совпадет, то его значение перезапишется

Comment: `split` по умолчанию и так делается по пробелам.