# как преобразовать список в строку

Tags: python

Дана строка слов, записать строку слов в противоположном порядке. Например, на входе: "Мама мыла раму." Выход: "раму мыла Мама".
Вот мой код, он не работает.

```
a=[]
a=input('Введите фразу:') .split()
a.reverse()
b=str(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для объединения элементов массива в строку можно использовать метод join

```
a = input('Введите фразу: ') .split()
a.reverse()
b = ' '.join(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Или проще [`print(*b)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)