# Как получить массив с абсолютными значениями элементов комплексных чисел другого массива?

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x

Есть массив `I`, допустим, состоящий из 1000 элементов. Каждый элемент является комплексным числом. Необходимо получить массив `J`, элементами которого будут значения модулей чисел массива `I`.

Как лучше сделать вычисление значений массива `J`?
Посчитать модуль каждого числа массива `I` в цикле? Или же это возможно сделать с помощью какой-нибудь функции?

Comment: можно использовать функцию `map` - на вход даете функцию вычисления модуля и массив, а на выходе получаете массив результатов выполнения функции модуля

Comment: ...но под капотом у `map` всеравно будет цикл, так что, по большому счету, какая разница? только если с т.з. пользы для широты кругозора -))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

In [30]: a = np.asarray([complex(1, 1), complex(-1, 2), complex(3, -6)])

In [31]: np.abs(a)
Out[31]: array([ 1.41421356,  2.23606798,  6.70820393])
```

Сравнение производительности:

для 1000 элементов:

```
In [17]: a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 1000) + 1j * np.random.randint(-10, 10, 1000)

In [18]: lst = a.tolist()

In [19]: a.shape
Out[19]: (1000,)

In [20]: len(lst)
Out[20]: 1000

In [21]: %timeit [abs(c) for c in lst]
1000 loops, best of 3: 244 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit np.abs(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 28 µs per loop
```

для 1.000.000 элементов:

```
In [23]: a = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 10**6) + 1j * np.random.randint(-10, 10, 10**6)

In [24]: lst = a.tolist()

In [25]: a.shape
Out[25]: (1000000,)

In [26]: len(lst)
Out[26]: 1000000

In [27]: %timeit [abs(c) for c in lst]
1 loop, best of 3: 402 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.abs(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 24 ms per loop
```

Comment: Я еще не очень хорошо знаю все тонкости Python. Что такое IN и OUT?

Comment: @АлексейВоронов, это так среда iPython маркирует ввод (`In`) и вывод (`Out`), далее идет порядковый номер строки. Т.е. сам код начинается после `In [20]: `

Comment: А вы поняли заголовок топика "Абсолютное значение каждого элемента массива"? Я что-то его не понял, где тут абсолютные значения.

Comment: @0xdb, я так понял, что речь о значениях по модулю - абсолютных значениях...

Answer (score 2):

То, что вам нужно, называется list comprehension.

Работает вот так:

```
your_list = [complex(1, 1), complex(-1, 2), complex(3, -6)]

abs_list = [abs(c) for c in your_list]

print(abs_list)
```

Здесь вторая строчка полностью эквивалента циклу:

```
abs_list = []
for c in your_list:
    abs_list.append(abs(c))
```

В современном python для похожих задач настоятельно рекомендуется использовать именно list comprehension, а не map, который вам посоветовали в комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

Для `numpy` массива:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1+1j, -1+2j, 3-6j])
>>> abs(a)
array([ 1.41421356,  2.23606798,  6.70820393])
```

Для Питон-cписка:

```
>>> L = [1+1j, -1+2j, 3-6j]
>>> [abs(c) for c in L]
[1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 6.708203932499369]
>>> print(*map(abs, L))
1.4142135623730951 2.23606797749979 6.708203932499369
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)