# Получение безымянных GET параметров в CGI скрипте

Tags: python, cgi

Пишу сайт с использованием cgi, необходимо получить неизвестное количество параметров без имени. Пример URL *http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/script.py?6&20&21&22&23*, для именованных параметров использовал  cgi.FieldStorage(), но в данном случае он ничего не возвращает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665619/how-do-i-access-the-urls-query-string-in-a-python-cgi-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметры всегда имеют имена, но не всегда имеют значения. Чтобы включить в  `FieldStorage()` и параметры без значений, передайте `keep_blank_values` аргумент:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi

print("Content-Type: text/plain\n")

form = cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=1)
print(*form)
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Чтобы запустить сервер для демонстрации, выполните в директории с `cgi-bin`:

```
$ python3 -mhttp.server --cgi --bind localhost
```

Если зайти по адресу:

```
$ python -mwebbrowser "http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/script.py?6&20&21&22&23"
```

то браузер покажет (с точностью до порядка, [см. `PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)):

```
21 23 22 6 20
```

Для запроса в вопросе также работает менее общее: [`os.environ['QUERY_STRING'].split('&')`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.7) и даже `sys.argv[1].split('&')` (если ни одно значение не задано—[если нет `'='` в `QUERY_STRING`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.4)).

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как работает *  в print(*form)? Единственное что я понял то что так выводятся элементы коллекции

Comment: @First_Spectr: добавил в ответ ссылку  на объяснение что \* делает (`list(form)` возвращает все ключи (имена параметров) как для словарей в Питоне).