# Вывести цифры заданные списками строк

Tags: python

```
введите сюда код
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
Zero = ["00"
      "0    0"
      "0    0"
      "0    0"
        "00"]

One = ['1',
     '1 1',
       '1',
       '1',
      '111']

Two = ['2',
     '2    2',
        '2',
      '2',
     '22222' ]

Three = ['3',
      '3    3',
         '3',
      '3    3',
         '3']

Four = ['4',
      '4 4',
    '4444444',
        '4',
        '4']

Five = ['55555',
        '5',
        '5  5',
             '5',
        '5  5',]

    Six = ['6 6',
         '6',
         '6 6 6',
         '6    6',
           '6']

Seven = ['7777777',
              '7',
             '7',
           ' 7',
           '7']

Eight = ['8',
      '8     8',
        '888',
      '8     8',
         '8']

Nine = ['9 9',
      '9    9',
        '9  9',
           '9',
       '9  9']

Digits = [Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine]
try:
    digits = sys.argv[1]
    row = 0
    while row < 1:
        line = ""
        column = 0
        while column < len(digits):
            number = int(digits[column])
            digit = Digits[number]
            line += digit[row] + " "
            column += 1
        print(line)
        row += 1
except IndexError:
    print("usage: bigdigits.py <number>")
except ValueError as err:
    print(err, "in", digits)
```

Мне надо вывести на консоль цифры.
а меня случается вот так:
000 00 00 000 111 11 11 111 2222 ...
как то так.

я пробовал так

```
Zero = ["""00
         0    0
         0    0
         0    0
           00"""]
```

но не помогло.

Использую Питон 3.5.

Comment: переводы строк для консоли Пушкин делать будет?

Comment: можно [использовать `pyfiglet` чтобы ascii-art напечатать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9632995/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что:

```
one_string = [
      "  00  "
      "0    0"
      "0    0"
      "0    0"
      "  00  "]
```

и

```
many_strings = [
      "  00  ",
      "0    0",
      "0    0",
      "0    0",
      "  00  "]
```

это разные вещи:

- `one_string` это список содержащий единственную строку, состоящую из объединения приведённых констант (разделённых пробелом в исходном коде):

  ```
  one_string == ['  00  0    00    00    0  00  ']
  ```

  В Питоне: `("a" "b") == "ab"` — строковые константы (literals) объединяются, если между ними только пробел (включая табы, новую строку итд). К переменным это не относится: `a b == ab` это `SyntaxError`
- `many_strings` это список содержащий много строк (разделённые запятыми в исходном коде):

  ```
  many_strings == ['  00  ', '0    0', '0    0', '0    0', '  00  ']
  ```

Вы хотите второй вариант:

```
print(*many_strings, sep='\n')
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

#### Результат

```
  00  
0    0
0    0
0    0
  00
```

Обратите внимание, я добавил пробелы для первой и последней строк.

Answer (score 0):

В Python3 можно использовать str.format() для выравнивания строки относительно нужного количества символов в строке. Т.е. такая конструкция самостоятельно отформатирует вывод в строку шириной n символов и сделает выравнивание влево, вправо, или по центру. Например, в вопросе не больше 7 символов в строке, поэтому можно сделать 7 символов в строке и выравнивание по центру, так:

```
many_strings = [
        "00",
      "0    0",
      "0    0",
      "0    0",
        "00"]

for s in many_strings:
    print("{:^7}".format(s))
```

**Результат**

```
  00   
0    0 
0    0 
0    0 
  00
```