# print(fzip) печатает <filter object at 0x0318C990> вместо (f1.zip, f2.zip...)

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, как я мне вывести список файлов в папке с определенным расширение?

Нашел на просторах интернета кусок кода:

```
import os

directory = './'
files = os.listdir(directory)
fzip = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.zip'), files)
```

Скрипт выполняется`print(fzip)` но я получаю вместо (f1.zip, f2.zip...) `<filter object at 0x0318C990>`

В чем может быть проблема?
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: `from glob import glob; glob.glob('/path/to/*.zip')` ?

Comment: Если вам интересно какие ещё варианты, кроме `listdir + endswith` могут быть (к примеру, `pathlib.Path(directory).glob('*.zip')`), то вы можете ваш оригинальный вопрос *"Поиск файлов по расширению в Python"* отдельно также задать (если поиск не находит такого вопроса).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) в Питоне 3 возвращает "ленивую" коллекцию—итератор. Чтобы получить элементы, необходимо обойти результат. К примеру, чтобы напечатать элементы через пробел:

```
print(*fzip)
```

См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Если вы хотите многократно обходить `fzip`, то сохраните результат в список при первом обходе:

```
zip_paths = list(fzip)
print(*zip_paths)
for path in zip_paths:
    # use path here...
```