# Как работает *b, = map(int, [1,2,3])

Tags: python-3.x

python 3

```
>>> *b, = map(int, [1,2,3])
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

И стоит ли так делать вместо `list(map(...))`?

Comment: Заходит человек в гугл, хочет найти "как это работает", и тут раз, ваш вопрос на 1 месте, и ответы на него, объясняют "как это работает". И не важно что именно "*это*" имелось ввиду ;-P

Comment: @Kromster критикуя - предлагай.

Comment: С точки зрения читабельности я бы так не делал (хотя я бы даже map не использовал)

Comment: @SmitJohnth Согласен с лозунгом, но не владею синтаксисом Питона

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Comment: @jfs там есть ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: нашел фывфывфыв

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это деструктуризация с остатком.
Помеченная звёздочкой переменная получает список оставшихся от деструктуризации по другим переменным элементов.

[Спецификация PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Покажу на примерах:

```
>>> a,b,c = map(int, [1,2,3])
>>> a,b,c
(1, 2, 3)

>>> a,*b = map(int, [1,2,3])
>>> a,b
(1, [2, 3])

>>> *a,b = map(int, [1,2,3])
>>> a,b
([1, 2], 3)
```

Соответственно:

```
>>> *a, = map(int, [1,2,3])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

- Явное лучше, чем неявное.
- Читаемость имеет значение.
- Должен существовать один — и, желательно, только один — очевидный способ сделать это.

Нужно выбирать путь наиболее точно выражающий твои намерения.
Поэтому `list(...)` явно предпочтительнее.

Comment: А почему запятая в `*a,` обязательна? И стоит ли так писать?

Comment: Про стоит ли дописал. Запятая нужна, чтобы обозначить список. Синтаксис деструктурирующего присваивания.

Comment: Деструктурирующего - это как по английски? Есть ссылка на доку?

Comment: Можно почитать прям [тут, на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/4282/list-destructuring-aka-packing-and-unpacking#t=2017020911113478585)

Comment: Интересно посмотреть на листинг дизассемблера. Есть доки на опкод `unpack_ex`?

Comment: Прям тут не хочу. Есть официальная?

Comment: Нашёл: [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: Хм, не знал, что распаковка работает для последовательности, а не только для списков/кортежей.

Comment: "extended iterable unpacking" можно как "расширенная распаковка коллекций" перевести. Стоит более явно в ответе подчеркнуть, что лучше просто `b = 1,2,3` (или `digits = list(map(int, "123"))`) вместо кода в вопросе использовать.

Comment: @jfs iterable - это не коллекция. В документации описано что это такое.

Comment: @SmitJohnth конечно это коллекция (составной объект). Не стоит путать "коллекция" (в широком смысле) с `collections.abc.Collection` (в узком смысле). В контексте переводимой *фразы*, слово "коллекция" особенно подходит (совокупность предметов с намёком на конечность—очевидно что распаковка только для конечного числа работает). Если вы знаете лучший перевод для этой *фразы*, то слушаю. В разных контекстах слово iterable (коллекция, из которой по одному можно объекты доставать—объект с `__iter__` методом, который итератор возвращает) на русском по разному переводится.

Comment: @jfs в данном случае это очевидно именно *объект с __iter__ методом, который итератор возвращает*. *"Если вы знаете лучший перевод для этой фразы, то слушаю. "* - я знаю что ваш перевод неправильный. Iterable в жаве, например, не переводится, т.к. это интерфейс. Про питон не знаю.

Comment: @SmitJohnth да, слово "коллекция" именно  объект с `__iter__` в данном случае описывает. Я вообще не вижу других объектов в рассматриваемой фразе. Мы с вами на сайте Stack Overflow *на русском* находимся: следует использовать русские слова когда возможно—в разумных пределах (как известно, [имена вещам давать одна из двух сложнейших задач в программировании](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html))

Comment: Отлично, приведите пример устоявшегося употребления слова "коллекция" в адрес iterable или последовательности (sequence). Открытый файл по-вашему тоже коллекция?

Comment: @SmitJohnth используйте @ синтаксис если хотите, чтобы мне приходили уведомления о ваших комментариях. Если вам до сих пор не ясно почему  "extended iterable unpacking" можно как "расширенная распаковка коллекций" перевести, то задайте отдельный вопрос (как эту фразу перевести—вы ваш вариант отказываетесь привести, может кто лучше вариант предложит). Расширенные дискуссии не следует в комментариях вести.

Comment: @jfs да нет. Это вы предлагаете переводить что-то определенным образом - вот вы и доказывайте. Можете отдельный вопрос создать. Разрешаю.