# Как упростить вывод и избавиться от инкремента?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция. Реализовал сортировку. Как можно упростить функцию чтобы избавиться от переменной i, ее инкремента и проверок i < 10.

```
def print_dict(json_file, words):
    i = 0
    print('======================================================'.format(json_file))
    for word in sorted(words, key=words.get, reverse=True):
        print("Слово '{0}' в тексте упоменается {1} раз".format(word, words[word]))
        i += 1
        if i == 10:
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмите срез от sorted:

```
def print_dict(json_file, words):
    print('======================================================'.format(json_file))
    for word in sorted(words, key=words.get, reverse=True)[:10]:
        print("Слово '{0}' в тексте упоменается {1} раз".format(word, words[word]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вывести 10 наиболее часто встречающихся слов:

```
for word, count in words.most_common(10):
    print(f"Слово {word!r} в тексте упоминается {count} раз")
```

где `words` это [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

К примеру, чтобы посчитать частоту слов, разделённых пробелами, со стандартного ввода (stdin) или в файлах заданных в командной строке и напечатать 10 самых популярных:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

words = Counter(word for line in fileinput.input() for word in line.casefold().split())
print(*[w for w, _ in words.most_common(10)])
```

Использование:

```
$ top10words *.txt
```

См. также [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)