# Как преобразовать словарь в list of named tuples?

Tags: python

Как преобразовать словарь `{word1:3, word2:1, word3:8,.....}` в `list []`, включающий в себя `named tuples`?

К примеру на вход подаю:

```
{'and': 6, 'api': 2, 'applications': 2, 'cloud': 4, 'design': 3, 'develop': 2, 'document': 3, 'for': 3, 'in': 3, 'maintain': 1, 'python': 3, 'services': 3, 'test': 2}
```

Получаем:

```
[Pair(word='design', count=3), Pair(word='develop', count=2), Pair(word='maintain', count=1), Pair(word='and', count=6), Pair(word='test', count=2), Pair(word='cloud', count=4), Pair(word='applications', count=2), Pair(word='in', count=3), Pair(word='python', count=3), Pair(word='document', count=3), Pair(word='api', count=2), Pair(word='for', count=3), Pair(word='services', count=3)]
```

Comment: Напишите как выглядит словарь и как будет выглядеть итоговый список

Comment: Из {'and': 6, 'api': 2, 'applications': 2, 'cloud': 4, 'design': 3, 'develop': 2, 'document': 3, 'for': 3, 'in': 3, 'maintain': 1, 'python': 3, 'services': 3, 'test': 2} получить:

Comment: [Pair(word='design', count=3), Pair(word='develop', count=2), Pair(word='maintain', count=1), Pair(word='and', count=6), Pair(word='test', count=2), Pair(word='cloud', count=4), Pair(word='applications', count=2), Pair(word='in', count=3), Pair(word='python', count=3), Pair(word='document', count=3), Pair(word='api', count=2), Pair(word='for', count=3), Pair(word='services', count=3)]

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import namedtuple


source = {'and': 6, 'api': 2, 'applications': 2, 'cloud': 4,
          'design': 3, 'develop': 2, 'document': 3, 'for': 3,
          'in': 3, 'maintain': 1, 'python': 3, 'services': 3,
          'test': 2
         }

Pair = namedtuple('Pair', ['word', 'count'])

res = [Pair(k,v) for k,v in source.items()]

print(res)
```

Comment: менее читаемая альтернатива: `list(map(namedtuple('Pair', 'word count'), *zip(*source.items())))`

Comment: @Александр Благодарю!

Comment: @jfs Благодарю!

Comment: @ivan.stal: если вы хотите понять как код из комментария работает, то убедитесь, что вы понимаете почему [`zip(*matrix)` транспонирует матрицу в Питоне](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279) (в этом  случае из списка пар получаются две колонки, которые в map передаются -- значения из первой колонки map передаёт в качестве первого аргумента в `Pair` (word), а из второй колонки в качестве второго аргумента (count)). См. также [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)