# декоратор для обработки ошибок

Tags: python-3.x, декоратор

Нужно написать декоратор, который действует так: если возникает ошибка в функции, то декоратор делает одно, если нет ошибки, то ничего.

Comment: А вопрос то в чём?

Comment: А что есть ошибка в функции?

Comment: @gil9red Даже если выражение или оператор синтаксически верны, они могут вызвать ошибку при попытке их исполнения. Ошибки, обнаруженные при исполнении называются исключениями (exceptions) и не фатальны безоговорочно: позже вы научитесь перехватывать их в программах на Python. http://pep8.ru/doc/tutorial-2.6/9.html

Comment: @Darth, спасибо кэп :) но я у автора спрашивал, мб он под ошибками не исключение имел ввиду, а что-то другое -- код, возвращаемый функцией, вывод ошибки в stderr и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Пример декоратора, который ловит и выводит исключение из функции, в которой исключение может возникнуть случайно:

```
import random


def my_decorator(fn):
    def wrapped():
        try:
            return fn()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)

    return wrapped


@my_decorator
def my_func():
    while True:
        if random.randint(0, 4) == 0:
            raise Exception('Random!')

        print('Ok')


my_func()
```

Пример консоли:

```
Ok
Ok
Ok
Error: Random!
```

Comment: Может, импорт за циклом делать?

Comment: @mkkik, импорт все равно будет только один раз производиться, но в принципе можно вынести из цикла

Comment: @user207200, готово :)

Comment: Благодарю за оперативность)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы предохранить имя оборачиваемой функции/docstring, можно использовать [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). Чтобы вызываемая функция могла произвольные аргументы принимать, можно использовать `*args`, `**kwargs` (см. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)):

```
import functools

def retry(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception:
                pass
    return wrapper
```

Этот декоратор заново функцию запускает в случае возникновения исключений. [Пример](https://github.com/rholder/retrying):

```
@retry
def do_something_unreliable():
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
    else:
        return "Awesome sauce!"

print(do_something_unreliable())
```

Этот код всегда печатает [Awesome sauce!](http://ideone.com/Yf88vr) даже если в 9 из 11 случаев при вызове недекорированной функции возникает `IOError`. Чтобы ограничить количество попыток:

```
import functools

def retry(max_tries):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for n in range(1, max_tries + 1):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception:
                    if n == max_tries:
                        raise
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Здесь `retry` *создаёт* декоратор (чтобы получить декоратор, необходимо вызывать `retry(max_tries)`). Пример использования:

```
import random

@retry(max_tries=5)
def do_something_unreliable():
    """Do something unreliably."""
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
    else:
        return "Awesome sauce!"

print(do_something_unreliable())
```

В этом случае, если функция не завершилась успешно за `max_tries` попыток, то последнее исключение перевыбрасывается.

Этот декоратор может быть расширен, чтобы установить задержку между попытками, совершать попытки по заданному условию, итд: [к примеру `retrying.retry`](https://github.com/rholder/retrying).