# Как сделать так чтобы я мог вводить неограниченное количество переменных в класс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Например у меня есть класс.

```
class Smth():
    __init__(self, что я должен написать здесь???):
        И здесь, чтобы инициализировать все переменные
```

И именно здесь я не знаю что делать. Если я не знаю точное количество элементов, которое будет введено, то как мне их инициализировать ???

```
a = Smth('a','b','c')
```

Comment: *args и **kwargs подробнее тут:  https://djangofan.ru/args-kwargs-python

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 2):

?

```
class Smth:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.l = list(args)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key, value)


S(1, 2, a='a', b='b')
```

Comment: а если мне нужен список?