# Передать аргументы в функцию

Tags: python, словари, функции

Как передать параметры функции как словарь. Пример:

```
d = dict(param='test')

def f(param):
    print param

f(d)
```

Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: можно, перевормулируйте вопрос

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def func(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

func(a=1, b=2, c=3)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить оператор `**`:

```
d = dict(param='test')

def f(param):
    print param

f(**d)
```