# Python 3.6 Разбить список на строки по n элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Здравствуйте, стоит такая задача:
на входе текстовый файл из n строк, в каждой строке которого одно слово

```
#word1
#word2
....
#wordn
```

необходимо на выходе получить текстовый файл, в каждой строке которого будет m слов (при этом количество n может быть не кратно m, т.е. в последней строке может быть слов < m)

```
def split(lst, size):
     arrs = []
     while len(lst) > size:
         pice = lst[:size]
         arrs.append(pice)
         lst = lst[size:]
     arrs.append(lst)
     return arrs
f1 = open(r'c:\hashtags.txt')
lines = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
list20 = str(split(lines,20))
f2 = open(r'c:\20 per line.txt', 'w')
f2.write(list20)
f2.close()
```

Если записать list20 в текстовый файл, то получаю только 1 строку и текст вида `[['#collegestudent\n', '#pictoftheday\n', '#flexibility\n', '#instabirthday\n', '#sunrise_sunsets_aroundworld\n', '#селфипалка\n', '#bookaddict\n', '#bodybuildingmotivation\n', '#birthdaycake\n', '#heavy\n', '#naildesigns\n', '#jobs\n', '#rims\n', '#motivation\n', '#liprings\n', '#tats\n', '#iloveheels\n', '#likesreturned\n', '#clouds_of_our_world\n', '#hungry\n']`

Прошу подсказать, как выходной файл привести к требуемому виду

```
#word1 #word2 ... #word20
#word21 ......... #word40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def chunk_data(data, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
        yield data[i:i+chunk_size]

with open(r'c:\hashtags.txt') as in_fh, open(r'c:\20 per line.txt', 'w') as out_fh:
    for lines in chunk_data(in_fh.readlines(), 20):
        out_fh.write(' '.join(i.strip() for i in lines)+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Файл это итератор над строками в Питоне, чтобы не загружать весь файл в память, можно разбить файл на группы по `m` строк, используя `zip(*[iterator]*m)` идиому, демонстрируемую в [itertools рецепте `grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Читая слова из одного файла и группируя их в выходном файле:

```
with open('words.txt') as file, open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for words in grouper(file, m, fillvalue=''):
        print(*map(str.strip, words), file=output_file)
```

К примеру для  ввода:

```
#word1
#word2
#word3
#word4
#...
```

и `m=2` [результат](https://ideone.com/qIdLYT):

```
#word1 #word2
#word3 #word4
#...
```

Для m=3 [результат](https://ideone.com/781Pnv):

```
#word1 #word2 #word3
#word4 #...
```

Для понимания кода может помочь: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)