# Разбить список на списки по заданному количеству элементов в списске

Tags: python, list

Есть список url пусть будет 65 штук, есть сайт который принимает по 30 максимум url за раз, как правильнее, проще и элегантнее скормить этот список сайту, по моей логике разбить список на список со списками, который будет выглядеть как-то так
[65шт.] = > [[30шт.],[30шт.],[5шт.]]
или делать цикл со счетчиком который будет считать каждые 30 штук и скармливать сайту ?

Comment: похоже на XY-проблему: вы можете использовать thread pool или semaphore, чтобы ограничить число одновременных соединений. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31784484/4279)

Comment: к задаче в заголовке: [Python 3.6 Разбить список на строки по n элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722299/23044)

Comment: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def chunkify(items, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(items), chunk_size):
        yield items[i:i+chunk_size]


chunks = chunkify(urls, 30)
```

Comment: зачем дублировать ответ, вместо того чтобы как дубликат закрыть?

Comment: @jfs потому, что я не нашёл свой прошлый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from funcy import chunks # pip install funcy
>>> array = list(range(1, 66))
>>> result = list(chunks(30, array))
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65]]
```