# Запутался со списками

Tags: python

У меня есть список:
**['4', '9', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8', '1', '6']**
нужно сделать вот так:
**[['4', '9', '2'], ['3', '5', '7'], ['8', '1', '6']]**
Я просто запутался, не пойму что делать.

Comment: [Разбить список на списки по заданному количеству элементов в списке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837188)

Comment: "вот так" это как? формализуй задачу. "Вот так" - плохо, за такое ругают. "Разделить на подсписки по три элемента" - хорошо, за такое хвалят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более простой и понятный для новичка способ. Используются лишь срезы, и метод `append`

```
a = ['4', '9', '2', '3', '5', '7', '8', '1', '6']
b = []
for i in range(0, len(a), 3):
    b.append(a[i: i + 3])
print(b)
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Все сразу ясно и понятно.