# Python заполнить двумерный массив 3x3 числами от 1 до 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

Вот код

```
a = [[0]*3]*3

counter = 0

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        print('At x=%d y=%d was appended %d' % (x, y, counter))
        a[x][y] = counter
        counter += 1

print(a)
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, вроде должен заполнять от 1 до 9, но в выводе получаю `[[6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8]]`. 
Добавил `print()` в цикле, показывает нормальное заполнение
Подскажите, где ошибка?

Answer (score 4):

В вашем примере создается список ссылок на один и тот же список. Попробуйте создавать список `a` таким образом:

```
a = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3) ]
```

Ну и `counter` стартовать с 1.

Можно еще так (при условии, что под массивом понимается список списков):

```
args = [ iter(range(1, 10)) ] * 3
l = [ list(t) for t in list(zip(*args)) ]
```

Comment: `list(zip(*[iter(range(1, 10))] * 3))` это жестокий способ матрицу 3x3 заполнить (обход коллекции по 3 элемента за раз). [Вложенный цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752649/23044) проще для понимания.

Comment: @jfs , согласен

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import count as count_from

count = count_from(1)
matrix = [[next(count) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Получаем: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

`[L]*3` создаёт список: `[L, L, L]`, то есть все элементы ссылаются на один и тот же объект ([Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)). Если `L` неизменяем, например число, то не имеет значения один объект или несколько используются. Но если `L` изменяем, как  к примеру список в вашем случае, то ваш код `a[x][y] = counter` изменяет один и тот же список, поэтому все ряды становятся равными последнему ряду (так как каждый ряд представлен одним и тем же списком).

Другими словами: `[0]*3` можно использовать. `[[0]*3]*3` не стоит использовать, а следует заменить на `[[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Вложенные списки это один объект.
Нужно что то вроде этого:

```
a = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Отлично, работает
Просто пока гуглил, часто сталкивался с конструкцией вида [[0]*3]*3

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще таким способом:

```
>>> result = [[j for j in range(i-2, i+1)] for i in range(3, 10, 3)]
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Или так:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(range(x-2, x+1)), range(3, 10, 3)))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```