# Двумерные массивы, в матрице все списки принимают одни значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Решал задачу на проекте Эйлера(https://projecteuler.net/problem=15)
При работе с матрицей входящие в нее массивы принимают одни значения.
Что я делаю не так ? 
тут код для квадрата 3х3.

```
mas = [[0] * 3] * 3
mas[0] = [1, 1, 1]
for i in range(3):
    mas[i][0] = 1

for l in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if mas[l][j] == 0:
            mas[l][j] = mas[l-1][j] + mas[l][j-1]
            print(mas[l-1][j] + mas[l][j-1])
```

изначально матрица выглядит так:

```
[1, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 0, 0]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 0, 0]
```

после должно получиться такое:

```
[1, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 3, 6]
```

НО получается,что массив номер 1 (после[1,1,1]),присваиваит свои значения другим и на выходе получаем:

```
[1, 1, 1]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                       
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Или вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752502/python-заполнить-двумерный-массив-3x3-числами-от-1-до-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
mas = [[0 for l in range(3)] for j in range(3)] 
mas[0] = [1, 1, 1]
for i in range(3):
    mas[i][0] = 1
print(mas)

for l in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if mas[l][j] == 0:
            mas[l][j] = mas[l-1][j] + mas[l][j-1]
            print(mas[l-1][j] + mas[l][j-1])
print(mas)
```

Ошибка в способе задания матрицы. 2-я и 3-я строки матрицы у вас являются ссылками на 1-ю строку.