# Избавление в python от ссылок в конструкциях lst*n

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Задам вопрос на примере. Необходимо построить матрицу(список списков) 8*8 и заполнить точками. `[['.']*8]*8` не подходит, при изменении, например, элемента `[0][0]` все элементы `[i][0]` меняются таким же образом. Как я понимаю, это связано с тем, что конструкция вида `lst*n` использует ссылки на изначальный массив. Как избавиться от этих ссылок и сделать элементы независимыми друг от друга?

Comment: См. также [Python заполнить двумерный массив 3x3 числами от 1 до 9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/752502/1365)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[['.' for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]`