# обратить слово без использования циклов с помощью рекурсии

Tags: python

Дефинировать функцию tagurpidi, что берет за аргумент слово и возвращает его в перевернутом виде(House = Esuoh). Без использования циклов. Функция должна работать еще если пустым словом.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Дефинируйте, только никогда больше не используйте это слово...

Comment: А точно от `House` должно получиться `Esuoh`? Мб, просто `esuoH`. В общем хитрый реверс с учетом регистра символа на его позиции: `def do_reverse(text): return ''.join(c.upper() if text[i].isupper() else c.lower() for i, c in enumerate(reversed(text)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще такой вариант:

```
In [33]: word = 'Hello'

In [34]: def do(word, index=-1, reversed_word=''):
    ...:     if len(reversed_word) == len(word):
    ...:         return reversed_word.capitalize()
    ...:     reversed_word += word[index]
    ...:     return do(word, index-1, reversed_word)
    ...:

In [35]: do(word)
Out[35]: 'Olleh'
```

Answer (score 2):

Аналог [`word[::-1].capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize):

```
def reversed_r(word, result=''):
    return reversed_r(word[1:], word[0] + result) if word else result.capitalize()
```

[Пример](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20reversed_r%28word,%20result%3D''%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20reversed_r%28word%5B1%3A%5D,%20word%5B0%5D%20%2B%20result%29%20if%20word%20else%20result.capitalize%28%29%0A%0Aprint%28reversed_r%28'House'%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=20&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false):

```
>>> reversed_r('House')
'Esuoh'
```

Можно обойтись без индексации:

```
def reversed_star(word, result=''):
    if not word:
        return result.capitalize()

    first, *rest = word
    return reversed_star(rest, first + result)
```

Результат тот же. См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия:

```
def definition(string, result=''):
    try:
        result += string[-1]
        definition(string[:-1], result)
    except IndexError:
        print(result)
        # print(result.capitalize())  -  'Esuoh'

definition('House')
# 'esuoH'
```

С возвратом значения (gil9red):

```
def definition(string, result=''):
    try:
        result += string[-1]
        return definition(string[:-1], result)
    except IndexError:
        return result.capitalize()

print(definition('House'))
```

Comment: Если `definition(string[:-1], result)` -> `return definition(string[:-1], result)` и `print(result)` ->`return result`, то функция будет именно возвращать результат

Comment: @gil9red добавил вариант