# Вчем разница между двумя способами создания списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list(string[:2]) + [string[2:]]

['S', 'p', 'am']
```

Кажется, что они делают одно и тоже но результат разный, и первая и вторая часть создают список, но по-разному, почему так?

Comment: я не совсем понял суть вопроса - можете уточнить?

Comment: литерал списка [[]], и list([]), по разному создают список, а делают одно и тоже

Answer (score 5):

По-моему разница в том, что конструктор `list()` проверяет является ли переданный ему аргумент итерируемым объектом и в том случае если это итерируемый объект - конструктор вернет список объектов возвращенных итератором. "list literal" `[]` таких проверок не делает - он просто создает список из переданных объектов.

Пример:

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i

In [23]: list(f(10))
Out[23]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [24]: [f(10)]
Out[24]: [<generator object f at 0x000000000A891F68>]
```

тоже самое происходит со строками (`string` в Python - итерируемый объект)

```
In [25]: list('abc')
Out[25]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [26]: ['abc']
Out[26]: ['abc']
```

проверка на итерируемость:

```
In [27]: import collections

In [28]: isinstance('abc', collections.Iterable)
Out[28]: True
```

Также `[]` отрабатывает быстрее чем `list()`, т.к. `list()` требует поиска в таблице методов:

```
In [64]: %timeit []
22.1 ns ± 0.0214 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [65]: %timeit list()
126 ns ± 3.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Стоит добавить что `list()` требует поиска в таблице методов, в то время как `[]` это часть синтаксиса и отрабатывает немного быстрее.

Comment: @Alban, спасибо! Добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

1. В  Python список не "объявляется". Но это неважно.
2. Первая строка склеивает строку из двух частей целого, а list() разбивает на список, состоящий из символов.
3. ['S', 'p', 'am'] - создает список из трех элементов.
4. если вы имели ввиду, что string = 'Spam', то надо было так и написать. А чтобы оно делало то же самое что и вторая строка  -   надо сделать следующее:

---

```
[string[0], string[1], string[2:]]
```

Comment: последнее можно переписать: `[*s[:2], s[2:]]` -> `['a', 'b', 'cde']` См. [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)