# Почему цикл for i in text: text[i] выдает ошибку TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x

При выполнении данного кода:

```
greeting = ['Здравствуйте', 'вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров', 'Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия']
i = 0
for i in greeting:
    print (greeting[i])
    i += 1
```

происходит ошибка:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Потому что вы число `i` меняете на строку в цикле `for i`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что ваша программа не доходит до шага сложения `i += 1`, так как у вас переменная `i` присваивается к значения массива и становится типом `str`  т.е. `greeting['Здравствуйте']` , после чего выполняется выражение `i + 1`  и выдается ошибка, что значение `i` является типом `str` и его нельзя сложить:

```
greeting = ['Здравствуйте', 'вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров', 
            'Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия']
# i = 0
for i in greeting:
     print(i)
     print(type(i))
```

**Вывод**

```
Здравствуйте
<class 'str'>
вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров
<class 'str'>
Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия
<class 'str'>
```

---

Для того чтобы у вас программа работала корректно вам стоит сделать:

```
greeting = ['Здравствуйте', 'вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров', 
            'Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия']
x = 0
for y in greeting:
    print(greeting[x])
    x += 1
```

или

```
greeting = ['Здравствуйте', 'вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров', 
            'Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия']
for y in greeting:
    print(y)
```

**Вывод**

```
Здравствуйте
вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров
Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия
```

Comment: код не доходит до `i+=1` здесь. TypeError на `greeting[i]` выражении выбрасывается. Фраза *«переменная i присваивается в массив»* не ясна. Имя `i` ссылается на текущий элемент списка на каждой итерации.

Comment: @jfs спасибо подредактировал

Answer (score 1):

В цикле `for i in greeting:` на каждой итерации `i` не является индексом, а ссылается на сам элемент в списке `greeting`. Поэтому `i` это строка, а не целое число.

К примеру, на первой итерации `greeting[i]` равнозначно `greeting['Здравствуйте']` и вызывает `TypeError`.

Чтобы напечатать приветствие на отдельных строках:

```
for s in greeting:
    print(s)
```

Или (кратко и работает также для нестроковых элементов):

```
print(*greeting, sep='\n')
```

[Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 0):

```
greeting = ['Здравствуйте', 'вам надо решить как можно больше правильных примеров', 'Ответ вписывайте после двоиточия']
i = 0
for x in greeting:
    print(greeting[i])
    i += 1
```