# Первое и последнее вхождение без метода count и циклов

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дана строка. Если в этой строке буква f встречается только один раз, выведите её индекс. Если она встречается два и более раз, выведите индекс её первого и последнего появления. Если буква f в данной строке не встречается, ничего не выводите. При решении этой задачи нельзя использовать метод count и циклы.

это решение которое проходит проверку:

```
s = input()
a = s.find('f')
b = s.rfind('f')
if a == -1:
    print()
elif a == b:
    print(a)
else:
    print(a, b)
```

есть ли решения это задачи которые бы соответствовали требованиям

> При решении этой задачи нельзя использовать метод count и циклы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### str.index

Чтобы распознать случаи: 0, 1, 2+ вхождений без явных циклов, `s.count('f')` метода, очевидная альтернатива `s.find()` методу из вопроса — это `s.index()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

s = input()
count = len(s) - len(s.replace('f', ''))
if count == 0:
    pass
elif count == 1:
    print(s.index('f'))
else: # count > 1
    print(s.index('f'), s.rindex('f'))
```

### try/except

Можно без явного `if`:

```
try:
    i = s.index('f')
except ValueError:  # count == 0
    pass
else:
    try:
        j = s.rindex('f', i+1)
    except ValueError:  # count == 1
        print(i)
    else:               # count > 1
        print(i, j)
```

### Рекурсия

Можно рекурсивный `find()` реализовать:

```
def find(char, s, i=0):
    return -1 if i == len(s) else i if char == s[i] else find(char, s, i+1)
```

Тогда решение почти идентично варианту из вопроса<sup>(разница в том, что *ничего* не выводится для `count==0` случая)</sup>:

```
s = input()
i = find('f', s)
j = len(s) - 1 - find('f', s[::-1])  # rfind('f', s)
if i == -1:   # count == 0
    pass
elif i == j:  # count == 1
    print(i)
else:         # count > 1
    print(i, j)
```

### Итераторы

Можно `find()` даже без индексации и явного `len(s)` реализовать:

```
def find(char, s, i=0):
    it = iter(s)
    first = next(it, None)
    return -1 if first is None else i if first == char else find(char, it, i+1)
```

### Распаковка аргументов

Можно вообще не вызывать явно встроенные функции, опираясь на [распаковку аргументов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044):

```
def find(char, s):
    def f(first, *rest, i=0):
        return i if first == char else -1 if not rest else f(*rest, i=i+1)
    return -1 if not s else f(*s)
```

### Связные списки

Используя это представление, можно со строками как со связными списками работать. К примеру, чтобы обратить строку, получив связный список:

```
def reversed_as_llist(s):
    def f(first, *rest, llist=None):
        return f(*rest, llist=(first, llist)) if rest else (first, llist)
    return f(*s) if s else None
```

Пример:

```
>>> reversed_as_llist('abc')
('c', ('b', ('a', None)))
```

Используя явные функции доступа:

```
first = lambda llist: llist[0] if llist else None
rest = lambda llist: llist[1] if llist else None
```

легко найти размер списка, реализовать поиск по аналогии с приведёнными решениями:

```
def llist_len(llist, size=0):
    return llist_len(rest(llist), size+1) if llist else size

def llist_find(char, llist, i=0):
    return -1 if not llist else i if char == first(llist) else llist_find(char, rest(llist), i+1)
```

Это позволяет определить `rfind()` без `len(s)` и индексации (`s[::-1]`):

```
def rfind(char, s):
    L = reversed_as_llist(s)
    i = llist_find(char, L)
    return i if i == -1 else llist_len(L) - 1 - i
```

При желании, можно отказаться и от рекурсии с именованными функциями (к примеру, используя Y combinator) и даже не использовать явно числа (к примеру, заменяя на Church numerals).

### heapq.nlargest

Если использовать встроенные функции, стандартную библиотеку, то есть множество решений, которые скрывают явный цикл и позволяют без `.count('f')` обойтись:

```
import heapq

indices = heapq.nlargest(2, range(len(s)), key=lambda i: s[i] == 'f')
fs = ''.join(map(s.__getitem__, indices))
if fs == 'ff':        # count == 2+
    print(*indices)
elif fs[:1] == 'f':   # count == 1
    print(indices[0])
# else print nothing  # count == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия вместо цикла:

```
def f_counter(string, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if string:
        if string[-1] in ('f', 'F'):
            result.append(len(string) - 1)
        return f_counter(string[:-1], result)
    return result

f_indexes = f_counter('asdfghjfaFdfgh')
if not f_indexes:
    print('nope!')
elif len(f_indexes) == 1:
    print(f_indexes.pop())
else:
    print(f_indexes.pop(-1), f_indexes.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    s = input()
    if (s.find('f') == -1):
        pass
    else:
        pos = s.index('f')
        pos1 = s.rindex('f')
        if (pos == pos1):
            print(pos)
        else:
            print(pos, pos1)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]: def search(task, letter, index=0, indexes=[]):
    ...:     if index == len(task):
    ...:         return f'First {min(indexes)}. Last {max(indexes)}'
    ...:     if task[index] == letter:
    ...:         indexes.append(index)
    ...:     return search(task, letter, index+1)
    ...:

In [29]: task = 'Hello from python fffff'

In [30]: search(task, 'f')
Out[30]: 'First 6. Last 22'
```

Answer (score 0):

данное решение использует переворот строки для поиска последнего вхождения и соответствует требованиям задачи (нельзя использовать метод count и циклы, кроме того - rfind на момент задания не преподавалось)

```
s = str(input())
b = s[::-1]
if s.find('f') == -1:
    print()
elif s.find('f') == (len(s) - b.find('f') - 1):
    print(s.find('f'))
else:
    print(s.find('f'))
    print(len(s) - b.find('f') - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()

pos1 = s.find('f')

if pos1 != -1:
    s = s[::-1]
    pos2 = len(s) - s.find('f') - 1
    if pos1 != pos2:
        print(pos1, pos2)
    else:
        print(pos1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
n = 0
pos = s.find('f')
lastPos = -1
if pos == -1:
    print()
elif s.find('f') != -1:
    while pos != -1:
        if pos != -1:
            n += 1
        pos = s.find("f", pos + 1)
        if pos != -1:
            lastPos = pos
if n == 1:
    print(s.find('f'))
elif n > 1:
    print(s. find("f"), s.find("f", lastPos))
```

Comment: Автор же циклы исключил