# Как изменить вывод результата в каждую строку отдельно?

Tags: python

Как изменить вывод результата в каждую строку отдельно?

```
import random, string
listToPrint = set()
while len(listToPrint) < 100000:
    listToPrint.add(''.join(random.choice("0123456789") for i in range(4)))
print(listToPrint)
```

Comment: стоит заметить, что цикл у вас никогда не закончится, так как длина `listToPrint` у вас не может превышать `10000` (количество разных 4-значных десятичных чисел).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(listToPrint))
```

Ещё можно написать так:

```
print(*listToPrint, sep='\n')
```

Звёздочка [распаковывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594652/235436) элементы коллекции и передаёт их в качестве отдельных аргументов. Параметр `sep` задаёт разделитель между аргументами.

Comment: А можно ли задать бесконечное множество вместо <10000 ?

Comment: @Дима, какая у вас задача?

Comment: генериорвать случайные числа

Comment: @Дима, и зачем вам бесконечное множество?

Comment: на тот случай если длина числа будет меняться, цеплять больший диапазон.

Comment: на тот случай если длина числа будет меняться, цеплять больший диапазон

Comment: @Дима, ну, генерировать случайные целые числа в диапазоне от a до b можно просто функцией random.randint(a, b). И задавайте тот диапазон, который нужен. Я не понял, что вы имеете в виду под бесконечным множеством.

Comment: и как не перегружать оперативку при больших количествах например(<1000000000)?

Comment: @Дима, опишите более подробно вашу задачу. Можно задать для этого отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Если в случайные целые числа добавить буквы например abcf то как записать диапазон? так? (0-9,a,b,c,)...

Comment: Задача генератор случайных чисел диапазон символов (0123456789abcdef) 32 символа в строке. Чтобы не перегружал оперативку при например while len(listToPrint) < 10000000000

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in listToPrint:
    print(i)
```