# Как создать список из переменной с определенным числом элементов в ней

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть переменная: `q_ty = 3`

Есть выражение: `text = 'abc'`

Необходимо сделать `list_text = ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']`

Другими словами, повторить переменную `text` некоторое кол-во раз.

Comment: list_text = [text]*q_ty

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Автор, сами оформите как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел

Comment: связанный вопрос [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
q_ty = 3
text = 'abc'
items = [text] * q_ty
print(items)  # ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```