# Найти соседей в матрице без использования циклов, логических операторов, операторов присваивания

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, индексация, функциональное-программирование

В заданном двухмерном массиве найти значения соседей для каждого элемента.

К примеру, массив:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Для элемента **"1"** соседи: [2, 4, 5] 
Для элемента **"5"** соседи: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
Т.е. элементы отличаются от текущего на индекс +- 1.

Сложность в том, что нужно решить только методами функционального программирования: рекурсии, and/or, map, reduce, zip и т.д. 
**НО** без использования циклов, логических операторов, операторов присваивания.

Comment: Интересно, с чего вдруг логические операторы стали противоположностью функционального программирования (стали как-то противоречить ФП?) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение без явных `for`, `if`, `=`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from functools import partial
from itertools import product

def all_neighbors(matrix):
    def neighbors(i, j):
        def valid_index(dij):
            return (any(dij)
                    and 0 <= (i+dij[0]) < len(matrix)
                    and 0 <= (j+dij[1]) < len(matrix[i+dij[0]]))
        return tuple(map(lambda dij: matrix[i+dij[0]][j+dij[1]],
                         filter(valid_index,
                                product((-1, 0, 1), repeat=2))))

    def row_neighbors(i):
        return tuple(map(partial(neighbors, i), range(len(matrix[i]))))

    return map(row_neighbors, range(len(matrix)))
```

Пример:

```
print(*all_neighbors([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]), sep='\n')
```

Результат:

```
((2, 5, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6, 7), (2, 4, 6, 7, 8), (3, 7, 8))
((1, 2, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 7), (2, 3, 4, 6, 8), (3, 4, 7))
```

---

Добавив по границам фиктивные элементы, можно обойтись без явной проверки границ для индексов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain, product
from operator import is_not

def add_edges(matrix,  sentinel=None):
    assert matrix
    return (list(chain([[sentinel] * (len(matrix[0]) + 2)],
                       map(lambda row: [sentinel] + row + [sentinel], matrix),
                       [[sentinel] * (len(matrix[0]) + 2)])),
            partial(is_not, sentinel))

def mesh(ys, xs, keep=lambda yx: True):
    return zip(*filter(keep, product(ys, xs)))

def all_neighbors_flat(matrix, not_sentinel):
    def neighbors(i, j):
        return tuple(filter(not_sentinel,
                            map(lambda di, dj: matrix[i+di][j+dj],
                                *mesh(*[(-1, 0, 1)]*2, keep=any))))
    return map(neighbors, *mesh(range(1, len(matrix)-1),
                                range(1, len(matrix[0])-1)))
```

Пример:

```
print(*all_neighbors_flat(*add_edges([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])), sep='\n')
```

[Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Здесь вывод плоский (все соседи подряд):

```
(2, 5, 6)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 4, 6, 7, 8)
(3, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 8)
(3, 4, 7)
```

Можно их по рядам сгруппировать как в первом примере показано.

### В сторону: о функциональном программировании (ФП)

Отсутствие/наличие `for`,`if`,`=` само по себе не делает программу "функциональной". ФП заключается в использовании [чистых (referentially transparent (RT)) функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (как функции в математике определяются). Как следствие, значения объектов не меняются, а только новые создаются выражениями, в декларативном стиле, в котором практически всё является значением, включая сами функции (отсюда использование "функций высшего порядка", которые функции принимают, возвращают).

---

Логические операторы `and`, `or` никак не противоречат ФП: для фиксированного ввода они всегда возвращают те же результаты, без побочных эффектов (RT). И даже short-circuit поведение этих операторов в духе ленивого вычисления только необходимых частей в ФП. Операторы доступны в виде значений как [функции в `operator` модуле](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

---

Использование "оператора присваивания" `=` (как он в Питоне определён) само по себе также не противоречит ФП. `a = 1` привязывает имя `a` к объекту, созданному `1` константой (так как int объекты неизменяемы в Питоне, то это может быть всегда один и тот же объект). Если `=` только раз для каждого имени используется, то (с точностью до NameError) можно всегда заменить имя на соответствующее выражение в правой части `=`. Использование имени в этом случае является просто syntax sugar, чтобы улучшить читаемость кода. Если запрещать `=`, то и именованные параметры в функции нельзя передавать (происходит привязывание объектов, переданных как аргументы, соответствующим именам при вызове функции) и `def` и `import` — всё это операции, которые имена вводят.

К примеру, два фрагмента один с `def`, другой с `=` и lambda одинаковый результат возвращают:

```
>>> def f():
        return 1
>>> f()
1
```

и

```
>>> f = lambda: 1
>>> f()
1
```

Есть небольшие отличия в значении `f` (`f.__name__`), но значения возвращаемые функциями идентичны:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): return 1
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> f = lambda: 1
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

Наличие `for`-циклов также не обязательно в конфликте с ФП. К примеру, если мы хотим получить квадраты чётных элементов коллекции:

```
def even_squares(items):
    return map(lambda x: x*x, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, items))
```

то отсутствие map/filter и наличие for/if никак результат не меняют [идиоматичный вариант]:

```
def even_squares(items):
    return (x*x for x in items if x % 2 == 0)
```

Как в случае с map/filter так и в случае с генератором (genexpr), `x` разным элементам входной коллекции соответствует. Есть формальное отличие в том, что `x` в одном и том же локальном контексте изменяется в genexpr, но это можно считать деталью реализации, syntax sugar ([генератор списков (listcomp) создавался для замены варианта с map/filter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#rationale) как  loop macro в Lisp или как наличие `do` нотации не превращает Haskell в императивный язык).

**Кратко:** формальное наличие циклов, логических операторов, операторов присваивания само по себе не противоречит функциональному стилю программирования.

Answer (score 1):

```
def in_bounds(i, j, x):                                                     
    return 0 <= i < len(x) and 0 <= j < len(x[0])                           

def neighbors(x):                                                           
    return [[x[i + di][j + dj] for di in (-1, 0, 1) for dj in (-1, 0, 1) if in_bounds(i + di, j + dj, x) and (di != 0 or dj != 0)]
            for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(len(x[0]))]               

x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]                                       
print(neighbors(x))
```

Вывод:

```
[[2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 3, 5, 8, 9], [4, 5, 8], [4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [5, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Но ведь в условии нельзя пользоваться for и if

Comment: Циклы здесь не используются. Почитайте про "списковые включения" в python, многое проясните. Это функциональная конструкция, заимствованная из функционального языка Haskell.

Что же касется логических операторов -- без них эту задачу не сделать.

Comment: map, reduce, zip разве не используют логические операторы и присваивание ?