# Неверный порядок выполнения алгоритма на Python в функциональной парадигме

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, функциональное-программирование

Нужно решить задачу полностью в функциональном стиле, т.е. в одну строку, без циклов (совсем нельзя использовать for) и без присваиваний.

Задача требует сначала ввести число `n`, затем вводится `n` последовательностей. К ним нужно применить функцию `zip` (дальше не важно, к вопросу не относится). Написал такой код:

```
print(*zip(map(lambda x: list(map(int, input().split())), range(int(input())))))
```

До применения `zip` всё правильно, но в `zip`, кажется, последовательности передаются по одной, так что, на практике выходит так:

Ввод:

```
2
0 0
1 1
```

Правильный вывод:

```
(0, 1) (0, 1)
```

Действительный вывод:

```
([0, 0],) ([1, 1],)
```

Как сделать правильно, и чтобы при этом оставаться в функциональной парадигме?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добавив к вашему решению одну звездочку можно получить необходимый результат:

```
print(*zip(*map(lambda x: list(map(int, input().split())), range(int(input())))))
#          ^  <--- NOTE
```

вывод:

```
(0, 1) (0, 1)
```

пояснение на примере:

```
In [159]: list(zip([[0, 0], [1,1]]))
Out[159]: [([0, 0],), ([1, 1],)]          #  то что получилось

In [160]: list(zip([0, 0], [1,1]))
Out[160]: [(0, 1), (0, 1)]                #  то что нужно получить

In [161]: list(zip(*[[0, 0], [1,1]]))     # решение
Out[161]: [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

PS [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651)

---

Функция `zip(*iterables)` принимает ноль и более позиционных аргументов и разница в вызове `zip(lst)` и `zip(*lst)` в том как будут обрабатываться переданные аргументы:

1. при вызове: `zip(lst)` - передается один аргумент типа `list`
2. при вызове: `zip(*lst)` - передается все содержимое списка как отдельные позиционные аргументы

Пример с функцией `print()`:

```
In [105]: lst = [1,2,3]

In [106]: print(lst)
[1, 2, 3]

In [107]: print(*lst)
1 2 3
```

тот же результат мы получим передав три раздельных параметра:

```
In [108]: print(1,2,3)
1 2 3
```

Comment: Прочитал, и всё же не понимаю: как эта звездочка воздействует на данную программу, так что с ней на вход подаётся сразу несколько iterable, а не по одному?

Comment: @DamocleDamoclev, я добавил некоторые пояснения, надеюсь так стало понятнее...