# Как построить запрос bulk_sentiment() из таблицы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Хочу с помощью онлайн сервиса оценить тональность текста. Он принимает запросы в следующем виде:

```
client.bulk_sentiment(text1='This is one block of text', text2='This is another block of text')
```

Как мне сформировать такой запрос из таблицы?

Есть таблица, например, такая:

```
Unnamed: 0                                              texts
0           0  В 000 ужасный сервис! В магазине, Санкт-...
1           1  Вопрос,что случилось с магазином самовывоза на...
2           2  Здравствуйте ZTE e-Learing Pad E9Q Black/Silve...
3           3  Здравствуйте. Ноутбук ASUS X75A HD+ вот такой ...
4           4  А подскажите в Туле на фрунзе цена какая? Спасибо
```

---

Текст возвращается вот такой функцией:

```
text = pd.DataFrame(data={'texts':texts})
```

Потом происхоидит вот это, не знаю зачем:

```
text.to_csv(path_or_buf="text.csv") 
text=pd.read_csv("text.csv")
```

Comment: Таблица у вас где и в каком виде хранится?

Comment: Ваша таблица очень похожа на Pandas DataFrame, полученный из неправильного парсинга CSV / Excel файла. Можете привести 2-3 строки исходного CSV в вопросе?

Comment: Текст возвращается вот такой функцией:`pd.DataFrame(data={'texts':texts})` потом происхоидит вот это, не знаю за чем `text.to_csv(path_or_buf="text.csv") 
text=pd.read_csv("text.csv") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блок:

```
text.to_csv(path_or_buf="text.csv") 
text=pd.read_csv("text.csv")
```

является излишним и кроме того здесь неправильно читаются данные обратно из CSV, т.к. `text.to_csv("text.csv")` добавит в CSV файл индекс и правильно читать такой CSV файл надо будет так:

```
text=pd.read_csv("text.csv", index_col=0)
```

---

предположим у нас есть правильно созданный DataFrame:

```
In [7]: text
Out[7]:
                                               texts
0        В 000 ужасный сервис! В магазине, Санкт-...
1  Вопрос,что случилось с магазином самовывоза на...
2  Здравствуйте ZTE e-Learing Pad E9Q Black/Silve...
3  Здравствуйте. Ноутбук ASUS X75A HD+ вот такой ...
4  А подскажите в Туле на фрунзе цена какая? Спасибо
```

мы можем легко создать словарь с аргументами для последующего вызова `client.bulk_sentiment()`:

```
In [9]: parms = text[['texts']].T.add_prefix('text').to_dict('r')[0]

In [10]: parms
Out[10]:
{'text0': 'В 000 ужасный сервис! В магазине, Санкт-...',
 'text1': 'Вопрос,что случилось с магазином самовывоза на...',
 'text2': 'Здравствуйте ZTE e-Learing Pad E9Q Black/Silve...',
 'text3': 'Здравствуйте. Ноутбук ASUS X75A HD+ вот такой ...',
 'text4': 'А подскажите в Туле на фрунзе цена какая? Спасибо'}
```

после этого можно вызывать `client.bulk_sentiment()` следующим образом:

```
client.bulk_sentiment(**parms)
```

Comment: Разобрался, почти! Подскажи,пожалуйста, как сделать именно как в примере чтобы было text0 = 'sometext", ..

Comment: @ВячеславЕфимов, не понял вопроса...

Comment: В представленном тобой пример параметры собираются в фигурные скобки и идут в виде: '"text0" : "В 000 удасеый сепрвс", "text1" : "safsadfs"'... мне же нужно чтобы параметры были именно так: 'text0 = "123123"'

Comment: @ВячеславЕфимов, [прочтите внимательно об использовании `**kwargs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5/594652#594652)

Answer (score 0):

```
texts = '''Unnamed: 0                                              texts
0    0  В 000 ужасный сервис! В магазине, Санкт-...
1    1  Вопрос,что случилось с магазином самовывоза на...
2    2  Здравствуйте ZTE e-Learing Pad E9Q Black/Silve...
3    3  Здравствуйте. Ноутбук ASUS X75A HD+ вот такой ...
4    4  А подскажите в Туле на фрунзе цена какая? Спасибо'''

lines = texts.split('\n')

params = {'text'+str(i):
          lines[i].split('\t')[-1]
          for i in range(1, len(lines))
          }

client.bulk_sentiment(**params)
```

Это будет работать для случая, когда у вас таблица задана тупо текстом, и колонки отделены табуляцией. Если это не так - то в код нужно внести соответствующие изменения.