# * с объектами в Python

Tags: python, print, range

Увидел такую конструкцию:

```
print(*range(5))
```

Попробовал в консоли и получил:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Попробовал без звёздочки и получил:

```
range(0, 5)
```

Я так понял, что это мини цикл for, да? Можете объяснить чайнику?

Comment: Нет. Это распаковка итерируемого объекта. Т.е. вместо `range(5)` в `print` подставляются элементы этого контейнера. Фактически при записи `print(*range(5))` у Вас вызывается `print(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: А, понял, спасибо

Comment: Таким образом, если у Вас, например, есть функция `f = lambda x,y,z: x+y+z` и переменные `a = range(2,4)` и `b = 8`, то запись `f(*a, b)` (распаковали только `a`) вызовет `f(2, 3, 8)` и вернёт `13`.

Comment: @ХорошийЧеловек это называется `распаковка (unpacking)`. Если вбить в гугл, будет несколько хороших статей. Соответственно, советую сразу прочитать и про `запаковку (zip)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит \* (звёздочка) и \*\* двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)