# Переменное число параметров в Python (по книге "A byte of Python")

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, параметры

Доброго времени суток всем. Кто может подробно разъяснить мне как это работает? Момент начинается со 2 строки и заканчивается на "return" (включительно). По остальной теме разобрался, на этом моменте ломаю голову. Извиняюсь, если неправильно оформил.

```py
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count

print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, vegetables=50, fruits=100))
```

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) неплохая статья, надеюсь поможет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит \* (звёздочка) и \*\* двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во второй строке в count записывается значение initial. Если вызвать функцию так print(total(initial=10)) или так print(total(7)), то программа выведет 10 или 7 соответственно. В третьей строке идёт цикл по всем значениям из numbers, которые получаются при задании positional arguments. В четвёртой идёт прибавление этих аргументов к count. В пятой идёт цикл по всем ключам из keywords, которые получились при задании keyword arguments. В шестой строке идёт прибавление значений от определённого ключа к count. Соответственно return отдаёт значение count.

Советую прочитать эту небольшую [статью](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/), тут дан подробный ответ на немного другом примере.