# Распаковка значений атрибутов экземпляра класса в значения атрибутов второго экземпляра при его инициализации

Tags: python, классы, наследование

У меня есть два класса: `One` и `Two`. Первый имеет атрибуты `aa`, `bb`, второй - собственный атрибут `cc` и унаследованные от `Two` `aa`, `bb` соответственно.
 
 Вопрос состоит в следующем: хочу иметь максимально экономичный способ при инициализации передавать в значения атрибутов экземпляра класса `Two`(`two_inst` в примере ниже) значения атрибутов уже существующего экземпляра класса `One`(`one_inst` в примере ниже). Другими словами, мне нужно при инициализации `two_inst` получить зачения`(cc='cc', aa='aa', bb='bb')`, но так, чтоб не руками `aa`, `bb` прописывать(и не в виде `aa = one_inst.aa, bb=one_inst.bb)`, а как-то разом перекинуть эти значения от `one_inst` при инициализации `two_inst`. 

 
 О том, что это можно реализовать циклом в конструкторе класса `Two`, я догадываюсь. Меня больше интересует, есть ли какая-то возможность корректно разворачивать, например, словари со значениями атрибутов одного экземпляра при инициализации экземпляра дочернего ему класса - что-то типа передачи `one_inst.__dict__` при инициализации `two_inst`, как на примере ниже

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, aa, bb):
        self.aa = aa
        self.bb = bb


class Two(One):
    def __init__(self, cc, *arg, **kw):
        self.cc = cc
        super().__init__(*arg, **kw)


one_inst = One(aa='aa', bb='bb')

two_inst = Two('cc', one_inst.__dict__) # я знаю что так это не работает (и не должно) - просто для демонстрации смысла того, что я хочу получить.
```

Comment: Вы были близки. `two_inst = Two('cc', **one_inst.__dict__)`. Но выглядит это очень грязно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы были близки.

```py
two_inst = Two('cc', **one_inst.__dict__)
```

---

Стоит посмотреть: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/324059)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сколько ж я времени убил в то время как все на поверхности лежал. А что значит "грязно" выглядит? Такой подход таит в себе какие-то потенциальные проблемы, которые могут возникнуть в дальнейшем при создании и использовании объектов, полученных таким образом?

Comment: @Kaderma При использовании проблем не будет. В дальнейшем, если кто-то будет пользоваться Вашим кодом, то он может захотеть дополнить класс `One` ещё каким-нибудь членом, который затем также будет распаковываться при инициализации `Two`, от чего появятся ошибки. Да и сами Вы можете через время к этому вернуться и тоже прийти в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите вариант создания объекта с помощью конструктора

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def create_related(cls, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        child = cls(*args, parent.__dict__, **kwargs)
        return child

class B(A):
    pass


a = A()
b = B.create_related(a)  # coздаст экземпляр "B" 
                         # скопирует аттрибуты объекта из "a"
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ