# Итерация по словарям в списке для получения нового списка

Tags: python, словари

Как можно произвести итерацию по словарям в списках:

```
list_1 = [{'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'Koly', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 2}]
list_2 = [{'count': 5}, {'count': 6}, {'count': 7}]
```

чтобы получить следующий результат:

```
merged_list = [{'count': 5, 'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 1}, {'count': 6, 'name': 'Koly', 'id': 4}, {'count': 7, 'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 2}]
```

Понятное дело, что я извлекаю каждый словарь через `for`, а потом объединенные словари при помощи `append` добавляю в новый список `merged_list`. Но как сделать чтобы они объединились в итоге?  Не могу придумать логику.

Comment: Не понял, чем ваш способ плох? Он порождает указанный результат.

Comment: @вася, необходимый результат порождает необходимый результат - не находите противоречий? ;)

Comment: @MaxU не понял. Почему *вытаскиваю каждый словарь через for, а потом объединенные словари при помощи append добавляю в новый список merged_list* неправильно?

Comment: @вася, мне кажется у автора проблема именно с `объединением словарей`

Comment: @вася, я не был знаком с использованием **a, **b, но  с методом zip уже работал, но тут не получилось самостоятельно его применить.

Comment: @АлексБалдр в вашем способе не нужен `zip()`, для добавления элемента в словарь можно использовать `dict.update()`

Comment: @вася, dict.update() не давал нужного результат. Я его и использовал первоначально с использованием циклов.

Comment: @АлексБалдр если бы вы привели свой код в вопросе, то можно было бы сказать, где ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
res = [{**a, **b} for a,b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [9]: res
Out[9]:
[{'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 1, 'count': 5},
 {'name': 'Koly', 'id': 4, 'count': 6},
 {'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 2, 'count': 7}]
```

или так:

```
res = [{**b, **a} for a,b in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

---

```
In [11]: res
Out[11]:
[{'count': 5, 'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 1},
 {'count': 6, 'name': 'Koly', 'id': 4},
 {'count': 7, 'name': 'Vacy', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: только нужно `**a` и `**b` поменять местами, у вас получается не совсем то что у автора в примере

Comment: где можно почитать про использование **b ? или это так называемые args & kwargs? Спасибо

Comment: @АлексБалдр, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/211923

Comment: @MaxU, премного благодарен!