# Превращение словаря словарей в список словарей

Tags: python, list, dict

Уважаемые коллеги такой вопрос.
Есть словарь словарей `{'asd':{'bbb':'aaa', 'ddd':'ggg'}, 'dsa':{'asd':'dsa','fgh':'hgf'}}`

Как бы мне его превратить в список словарей вида

```
[{'any_key':'asd', 'bbb':'aaa','ddd':'ggg'}, {'any_key':'dsa', 'asd':'dsa','fgh':'hgf'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {'asd':{'bbb':'aaa', 'ddd':'ggg'}, 'dsa':{'asd':'dsa','fgh':'hgf'}}
res = [ {'any_key':k, **v} for k,v in d.items()]
print(res)
```

res:

```
[{'any_key': 'asd', 'bbb': 'aaa', 'ddd': 'ggg'}, {'any_key': 'dsa', 'asd': 'dsa', 'fgh': 'hgf'}]
```

Comment: Объясни пожалуйста как работает **v ?

Comment: [Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/324059).

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
d = {'asd':{'bbb':'aaa', 'ddd':'ggg'}, 'dsa':{'asd':'dsa','fgh':'hgf'}}

print([{'any_key': k, **v} for k, v in d.items()])
```

Comment: Спасибо, можешь объяснить как работает **v?

Comment: @maiseo4allPYwarrior распаковка словаря -- Михаил Муругов скинул ссылку под соседним ответом