# Как узнать, что второе значение не равно -1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такие данные:

```
[(1, 15772), (2, 15773), (3, 15778), (4, -1), (5, 15766), (6, 15776), (7, -1), (8, 15777), (9, -1), (10, 15770), (11, -1)]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать, что значение не равно -1?
То-есть для (1, 15772) - что 15772 не равно -1, потом 15773 не равно -1

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вашу реализацию и что не выходит?

Comment: Я только начинаю учиться. Нет понимания как это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = [(1, 15772), (2, 15773), (3, 15778), (4, -1), (5, 15766), (6, 15776), (7, -1), (8, 15777), (9, -1), (10, 15770), (11, -1)]
```

```
for d in data:           # переберите все элементы списка
    if d[1] != -1:       # сравните второе значение (d[1] индексы начитаются с 0) с -1
        print(d)         # печать элемента, если не -1
```

распечатает только элементы списка со вторым значением, не равным -1:

```
(1, 15772)
(2, 15773)
(3, 15778)
(5, 15766)
(6, 15776)
(8, 15777)
(10, 15770)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно не знал как работать по вторым значением.                                                                   for work in results:
    if work[1] != -1:
        sectorwork += 1
print(sectorwork)

Comment: @Ando https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html

Answer (score 5):

Просто:

```py
print(*(a for a in data if a[1] != -1))
```

а можно так:

```py
print(*filter(lambda x: x[1] != -1, data))
```

Или без префиксной "звездочки":

```py
for i in filter(lambda x: x[1] != -1, data):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что делает * в print?

Comment: @Ando, )) а что это вы передумали? Вытаскивает из tuple элементы и передает функции. На вход функции подается, примерно такого вида `print((1, 15772), (2, 15773), (3, 15778), ...)`

Comment: @Ando, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5239856/9210255

Comment: @Ando https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/400096