# Почему внутри функции не работает цикл for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Передача произвольного набора аргументов.
Почему цикл `for` внутри функции не возвращает последовательно содержание всего кортежа, а выводит его только целиком?

```
def get_sndwch_info(*sandw_func_list):
    print("Состав сендвича: ")
    for name in sandw_func_list:
        print(f" - {name}")
  
sandwich_list = ['хлеб', 'плавленный сыр', 'лук', 'колбаса', 'бекон']
get_sndwch_info(sandwich_list)
```

Почему ниже в коде, все работает ?
Передаем аргументы они упаковываются в кортеж, и итерируются по одному?

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings):
    '''Выводсписка заказанных топингов'''
    print(f"\nMaking a {size} pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print(f"- {topping}")

make_pizza(16, 'paperoni')
make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra chise')
```

Comment: Либо уберите звездочку в заголовке функции, либо добавьте ее перед аргументом при вызове функции (чтобы список "распаковался" в отдельные аргументы).

Comment: Благодарю все работает, если применить ваши рекомендации. Но почему ранее в коде о пицце все работало без * при вызове функции?

Comment: Добавил ответом

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит \* (звёздочка) и \*\* двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Звездочка перед аргументом в заголовке функции "собирает" все позиционные (перечисленные последовательно) аргументы в кортеж. Но по факту вы передаете один позиционный аргумент - список `sandwich_list`. В итоге в `sandw_func_list` получается кортеж из одного элемента - списка, который выведется в первой итерации цикла.

Чтобы заработало правильно, нужно либо убрать звездочку перед аргументом в заголовке функции, либо добавить ее при передаче перед `sandwich_list`, чтобы элементы списка распаковались в отдельные позиционные аргументы, а внутри списка собирались в кортеж.

> Почему ниже в коде, все работает?

Потому что в этом примере аргументы перечисляются (передаются как отдельные позиционные аргументы), а не передаются одним аргументом-списком. Пример как "сломать", чтобы работало как в первом примере:

```
make_pizza(12, ['mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra chise'])
```

И как исправить обратно:

```
make_pizza(12, *['mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra chise'])
```

Answer (score 2):

А вы посмотрите, что у вас в функции получилось в `sandw_func_list`:

```
(['хлеб', 'плавленный сыр', 'лук', 'колбаса', 'бекон'],)
```

Когда вы использовали звёздочку в аргументе функции, вы запаковали аргумент в кортеж. Когда вы по нему итерируетесь, он просто распаковывается обратно в список, но сам список уже не итерируется. Просто уберите звёздочку из описания функции.