# Как определить данные кортежа в функцию

Tags: python

как я могу определить данные кортежа в функцию, к примеру:

```
def square(x, y):
    s = x * y
    return S
```

Если я хочу добавить ее в другой файл с кортежем и использовать данные кортежа в качестве x, y:

```
a = (4, 5)
```

то как мне это сделать?

Comment: уточните, что именно вы хотите сделать. я, лично, ничего не понял :(

Comment: например, `square(*a)`

Comment: `square(*a)` - если в кортеже __строго__ два значения

Comment: Спасибо, способ с *a работает, а как это верно называется, чтобы почитать по этому поводу?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте кортеж одним параметром:

```
def square(x):
    s = x[0]*x[1]
    return s
a = (4,5)
print(square(a))
```