# Функция которая принимает неограниченное количество словарей и возвращает объединяющий их словарь Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Как написать функцию, которая принимает неограниченное количество словарей и возвращает объединяющий их словарь?

При этом все значения в словаре имеют числовое значение, если ключи совпадают то их значения суммируются, числа в значениях могут быть как положительными так и отрицательными.

Пример словарей:

```
first = {"a": 2, "b": 4};
second = {"a": 2, "b": 10};
third = {"d": -5};
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 14, 'd': -5}
```

Пробовал так, но это не подходит:

```
def sum_dicts(dict1, dict2) -> dict: 
    dict3 = Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2) 
    return dict3
```

Также пробовал объединять через `{**dict1, **dict2}`, тоже не подходит.

Comment: Добавьте пример того, что вы хотите получить, и что вы уже попробовали

Comment: пробовал так, но это не подходит: def sum_dicts(dict1, dict2) -> dict:
    dict3 = Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2)
    return dict3

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос нажав "Править"

Comment: также пробовал объединять через {**dict1, **dict2} тоже не подходит

Comment: Ну если неограниченное количество, то наверное как минимум функция должна принимать [*args](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651)

Comment: Добавил в сам текст

Comment: добавить * args, потом перебирать в цикле и складывать?

Comment: dict{**dict1, **dict2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый элегантный и простой способ - использовать `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

first = {"a": 2, "b": 4};
second = {"a": 2, "b": 10};
third = {"d": -5};


def get_sum_dict(*dicts):
    result = Counter()
    for d in dicts:
        result.update(d)
    return dict(result)


print(get_sum_dict(first, second, third))
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 14, 'd': -5}
```

В вашей попытке оператор `+` для объектов типа `Counter` не сработал так, как вы хотели, потому что `Counter` реализован таким образом, что ключи с отрицательными значениями не учитываются в результате, поэтому во избежание такого поведения следует использовать метод `update()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dicts:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if key in result:
                result[key] += value
            else:
                result[key] = value
    return result

first = {"a": 2, "b": 4}
second = {"a": 2, "b": 10}
third = {"d": -5}

merged_dict = merge_dicts(first, second, third)
print(merged_dict)
```

На выходе получается:

```
{'a': 4, 'b': 14, 'd': -5}
```

Отмечу, что эта функция использует оператор * для передачи неограниченного количества аргументов в функцию как кортеж. И использует цикл for для обхода каждого словаря и внутри цикла другой цикл for для прохода по ключам и значениям каждого словаря. Если ключ уже есть в результирующем словаре, то значение ключа увеличивается, если это не так, то создается новый ключ с данным значением.