# Я хотел бы узнать что делают args и kwargs в Python

Tags: python

Я ещё новичок в программировании на Python, и я не понимаю некоторых вещей, например args и kwargs.
Я уже читал много пабликов там пишут как то непонятно для меня
можете рассказать что они делают только понятно, простым языком и как их использовать, заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/1984

Comment: - "я не понимаю некоторых вещей, например args и kwargs"

- Если совсем по простому, то args - это **список** (в смысле языка Python) **позиционных** аргументов функции. а kwargs - это **словарь**  (в смысле языка Python) **ключевых** аргументов этой функции. В Python свободные и сложные правила использования позиционных и ключевых аргументов. Коротко на этот вопрос не ответить.