# Как вывести все нужные числа в функции пайтон

Tags: python

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
def min5(a):
    for el in a:
        while el < 5:
            return el
print(min5(lst))
```

Выводит только первое число

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `yield` вместо `return`, ну и не `while`, а `if`, конечно. И результат ещё нужно будет "развернуть", например [оператором `*`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%91%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9):

```py
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
def min5(a):
    for el in a:
        if el < 5:
            yield el
print(*min5(lst))
# 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться списковым включением:

```
def min5(list_):
    return [item for item in list_ if item < 5]
    
print(min5([1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 0])) # [1, 3, 4, 0]
```

## Что за списковые включения?

Списковое включение (List Comprehension) - Краткая синтаксическая конструкция для создания списков. Своего рода "синтаксический сахар"

```
[ <Выражения для каждого> for <Элемента> in <Из последовательности> ]
```

В них также можно использовать условия:

```
[ <Выражения для каждого> for <Элемента> in <Из последовательности> if <Условие отбора>]
```

Они на самом деле мощнее, чем кажутся и это явно не весь функционал, на который они способны. Но ваши условия это покрывает

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто создать список, добавлять в него, а затем вернуть:

```py
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
def min5(a):
    result = []
    for el in a:
        if el < 5:
            result.append(el)
    return result
print(min5(lst))
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну или через `generator expression`

```
def min5(a):
    return (num for num in a if num < 5)

lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
print(*min5(lst))
```

`result`

```
1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема состоит в том, что команда первая встреча команды `return` — *вопреки тому, что она находится в цикле* — по своей природе **прекращает вес вызов функции.** Второй встречи этой команды к сожалению уже не будет.

И так

- вместо команды `return el` используйте `print(el)`, и затем
- вместо `print(min5(lst))` примените просто `min5(lst)`.